# Converting strings to enum in C++?

Tags: c++, enums

[Strings to enum in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/converting-a-string-to-an-enumeration-value-in-c), how do you normally converting strings to enum in C++. Any helper function that you use, is it a good idea to do this.

Comment: I should point that using strings as enums is probably a poor design choice.

Answer (score 2):

I reviewed this approach awhile ago - available via [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/EnumBinder.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to use a std::map or hash_map data structure.

Comment: or boost/TR1 unordered_map (instead of the non-standard hash_map)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <EnumString.h>
```

from http://codeproject.com/Articles/42035/Enum-to-String-and-Vice-Versa-in-C and after

```
enum FORM {
    F_NONE = 0,
    F_BOX,
    F_CUBE,
    F_SPHERE,
};
```

insert

```
Begin_Enum_String( FORM )
{
    Enum_String( F_NONE );
    Enum_String( F_BOX );
    Enum_String( F_CUBE );
    Enum_String( F_SPHERE );
}
End_Enum_String;
```

Work fine, if values in enum are not dublicate.

Example in code

```
enum FORM f = ...
const std::string& str = EnumString< FORM >::From( f );
```

and vice versa

```
assert( EnumString< FORM >::To( f, str ) );
```