# Converting a string to an enum in C#

Tags: c#, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting a string to an enumeration value in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/converting-a-string-to-an-enumeration-value-in-c)

How do I convert a enum to a string in C#?

Note:  I have the answer and will post, I searched for the answer here first but couldn't find it so I thought I would add the question / answer to the site once I found it.

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/converting-a-string-to-an-enumeration-value-in-c

Comment: I voted to close "exact duplicate". Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/converting-a-string-to-an-enumeration-value-in-c/16104

Comment: Totally agree no idea why it didn't come up in my initial search...  I will delete.

Comment: FYI search string used: "string to enum in c#"  Any idea why it wouldn't come and why the check while writing the subject didn't turn it up?

Comment: Question is: why doesn't question 16100 even show up in the Related sidebar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting is actually quite easy.  You would use the following function that is built in:

```
object Enum.Parse(System.Type enumType, string value, bool ignoreCase);

enum TEST_ENUM
{
  VALUE1,
  VALUE2
}

// To convert from a string to a enum just do the following
string sTestEnum = "VALUE2";

TEST_ENUM eDatabase = (TEST_ENUM)(Enum.Parse(typeof(TEST_ENUM), sTestEnum, true));
```