# C# WinForms DataGridView background color rendering too slow

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm painting my rows in a DataGridView like this:

```
private void AdjustColors()
    {            
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in aufgabenDataGridView.Rows)
        {
            AufgabeStatus status = (AufgabeStatus)Enum.Parse(typeof(AufgabeStatus), (string)row.Cells["StatusColumn"].Value);

            switch (status)
            {
                case (AufgabeStatus.NotStarted):
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightCyan;
                    break;
                case (AufgabeStatus.InProgress):
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LemonChiffon;
                    break;
                case (AufgabeStatus.Completed):
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.PaleGreen;
                    break;
                case (AufgabeStatus.Deferred):
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightPink;
                    break;
                default:
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
                    break;
            }
        }        
    }
```

Then I call it in the OnLoad method:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);

            AdjustColors();           
        }
```

I prefer OnLoad to OnPaint or something.. because OnPaint is called very often.

The question: Why does it take about 100 - 200 ms to change the background of every row?
Early, I was doint CellPaint.. but I had problems when scrolling with refreshing..

Comment: You mean it takes 100 - 200ms per row? That sounds pretty heavy.

Comment: How many rows? Do you have double-buffering set on the form? Have you tried using the CellFormatting event?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of changing the color of the whole `DataGrid` at once, you should let it manage the rendering by overriding the `CellFormatting` event. The rows will only be painted when they are actually displayed on the screen.

```
private void aufgabenDataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
  DataGridViewRow row = aufgabenDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
  AufgabeStatus status = (AufgabeStatus) Enum.Parse(typeof(AufgabeStatus), (string) row.Cells["StatusColumn"].Value);

  switch (status)
  {
    case (AufgabeStatus.NotStarted):
      e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightCyan;
      break;
    case (AufgabeStatus.InProgress):
      e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.LemonChiffon;
      break;
    case (AufgabeStatus.Completed):
      e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.PaleGreen;
      break;
    case (AufgabeStatus.Deferred):
      e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightPink;
      break;
    default:
      e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
      break;
  }
}
```

If this is still too slow, try getting the real object the row is bound to:

```
...
DataGridViewRow row = aufgabenDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
var aufgabe = (Aufgabe) row.DataBoundItem;
AufgabeStatus status = aufgabe.Status;
...
```

Comment: That could be a proof that I can't handling painting myself but I should rely on the mechanism provided by MS. 

Now all the rows are recolored immediately !

Comment: And I removed that Enum.Parsing as proposed by ShDevMan

Comment: +1 thanks...I always forget which event to do this in. This will run for each cell correct? I wish there was an event that only fired once per row?

Comment: If you want to change the color of single cells, then test for which cell the event was raised: if (e.ColumnIndex == piecePartMasterGridview.Columns["AufgabeStatus"].Index)

Answer (score 2):

Its probably the Enum.Parse call, it has poor performance.  You should try and change it to a dictionary lookup to see if that improves performance.  See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/converting-a-string-to-an-enumeration-value-in-c/38711#38711)

Comment: You are right, that Enum.Parse is slow enough. I rather access the DataBoundItem directly.

Answer (score 2):

As SwDevMan1 said, you should first work on removing the Enum.Parse call. Are you using data binding to populate the grid? If so, you can use Rows[index].DataBoundItem to access the data bound object for the row and access the AufgabeStatus status directly.

The second tweak I would suggest is to call SuspendLayout() and ResumeLayout() before and after, respectively, manipulating the grid.

Comment: I removed the Parse call. Yes I'm using DataBounding. I accessed the element directly through DataBoundItem. I tried Suspend & Resume. It's quicker.. but 15 rows are still coloured in about 400ms..

Answer (score 2):

It's also a good idea to only set the properties if they differ from the expected value. That way you don't trigger unwanted internal DataGridView overhead.

If all cells in a row are formatted the same way, you can do the formatting on row level instead of cell level.

```
DataGridViewCellStyle rowStyle = row.DefaultCellStyle;
if (rowStyle.BackColor != status.BackColor) { 
   rowStyle.BackColor = status.BackColor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

don't try row format 
as row.defaultcellstyle

try individual cell formatting in 
ufgabenDataGridView_CellFormatting

cell[0].style.backcolor=color.yellow