# How to conver a string to a enum of type int?

Tags: c#, enumeration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I Convert a string to an enum in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-c)

I have an enum of type int:

```
public enum BlahType
{
       blah1 = 1,
       blah2 = 2
}
```

If I have a string:

```
string something = "blah1"
```

How can I convert this to BlahType?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse.aspx)

```
BlahType blahValue = (BlahType) Enum.Parse(typeof(BlahType), something);
```

Answer (score 8):

I use a function like this one

```
public static T GetEnumValue<T>(string value)
{
    return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value);
}
```

And you can call it like this

```
BlahType value = GetEnumValue<BlahType>("Blah1");
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this function to convert a string to a enum; then you can cast to int or whatever.

```
public static T ToEnum<T>(string value, bool ignoreUpperCase)
        where T : struct, IComparable, IConvertible, IFormattable {
        Type enumType = typeof (T);
        if (!enumType.IsEnum) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
        return (T) Enum.Parse(enumType, value, ignoreUpperCase);
}
```

Comment: Nice extension method. I just wonder why should it ignore uppercase only rather than just ignore case? ;)

Comment: When I first did that function, I though about checking for if the given type was an enum. I gave up after discovering (with reflector) that Enum.Parse already do these check (and more) and throw a ArgumentException if the type is not an enum.

Comment: sorry, that's a spanish translation issue, it's just a wrapper for the overload of Enum.Parse

Answer (score 1):

```
    public enum BlahType
    {
        blah1 = 1,
        blah2 = 2
    }

    string something = "blah1";
    BlahType blah = (BlahType)Enum.Parse(typeof(BlahType), something);
```

If you are not certain that the conversion will succeed - then use [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991876(VS.100).aspx) instead.