# Search for a string in Enum and return the Enum

Tags: c#, string, enumeration

I have an enumeration:

```
public enum MyColours
{
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue,
    Yellow,
    Fuchsia,
    Aqua,
    Orange
}
```

and I have a string:

```
string colour = "Red";
```

I want to be able to return:

```
MyColours.Red
```

from:

```
public MyColours GetColour(string colour)
```

---

So far i have:

```
public MyColours GetColours(string colour)
{
    string[] colours = Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyColours));
    int[]    values  = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyColours));
    int i;
    for(int i = 0; i < colours.Length; i++)
    {
        if(colour.Equals(colours[i], StringComparison.Ordinal)
            break;
    }
    int value = values[i];
    // I know all the information about the matched enumeration
    // but how do i convert this information into returning a
    // MyColour enumeration?
}
```

As you can see, I'm a bit stuck.  Is there anyway to select an enumerator by value.  Something like:

```
MyColour(2)
```

would result in

```
MyColour.Green
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I Convert a string to an enum in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-c)

Comment: @nawfal, didn't find that when I asked this all those years ago. Have voted to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 433, accepted):

check out System.Enum.Parse:

```
enum Colors {Red, Green, Blue}

// your code:
Colors color = (Colors)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(Colors), "Green");
```

Comment: Don't forget you can have it ignore case sensitivity by passing in a third optional parameter to be "true"

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for ! Cheers !

Comment: @user1531040  Actually, there is an Enum.TryParse.

Comment: Note that enum parsing always 'succeeds' if the input is numeric; it just returns the parsed number, which then get cast to the enum's type. So if you want to check if some user input is a valid enum or something else, you should check for numeric content first. Since it returns a valid enum but with a value that may not exist at all in the defined enum names, you can get some really weird problems.

Answer (score 24):

You can cast the int to an enum

```
(MyColour)2
```

There is also the option of Enum.Parse

```
(MyColour)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyColour), "Red")
```

Answer (score 21):

Given the latest and greatest changes to .NET (+ Core) and C# 7, here is the best solution:

```
var ignoreCase = true;
Enum.TryParse("red", ignoreCase , out MyColours colour);
```

colour variable can be used within the scope of Enum.TryParse

Comment: what about `Enum.Parse<MyColors>("red", true)`

Answer (score 5):

All you need is [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

```
var color =  Enum.Parse<Colors>("Green");
```

Comment: This doesn't even compile. There is no generic `Parse` method.

Comment: It compiled & worked for me. Maybe it depends on the version you are using? I'm using .NET core 3.1

Comment: `var color =  Enum.Parse<Colors>("Green", true);` i suppose IgnoreCase had been forgotten.

Answer (score 2):

I marked OregonGhost's answer +1, then I tried to use the iteration and realised it wasn't quite right because Enum.GetNames returns strings. You want Enum.GetValues:

```
public MyColours GetColours(string colour)
{  
   foreach (MyColours mc in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyColours))) 
   if (mc.ToString() == surveySystem) 
      return mc;

   return MyColors.Default;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Enum.Parse` to get an enum value from the name. You can iterate over all values with `Enum.GetNames`, and you can just cast an int to an enum to get the enum value from the int value.

Like this, for example:

```
public MyColours GetColours(string colour)
{
    foreach (MyColours mc in Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyColours))) {
        if (mc.ToString().Contains(colour)) {
            return mc;
        }
    }
    return MyColours.Red; // Default value
}
```

or:

```
public MyColours GetColours(string colour)
{
    return (MyColours)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyColours), colour, true); // true = ignoreCase
}
```

The latter will throw an ArgumentException if the value is not found, you may want to catch it inside the function and return the default value.

Comment: NOTE: It should have been Enum.GetValues, of course, as shown in Colin's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method.

```
public static class Helper
{
  public static T FromStr<T>(string str) where T : struct, System.Enum
    => System.Enum.TryParse<T>(value:str,ignoreCase:true,result:out var result)
    ? result
    : default;
  public static T? FromStrNull<T>(string str) where T : struct, System.Enum
    => System.Enum.TryParse<T>(value: str,ignoreCase: true,result: out var result)
    ? result
    : null;
}
```

And use it like this

```
var color = Helper.FromStr<MyColours>("red");
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in previous answers, you can cast directly to the underlying datatype (int -> enum type) or parse (string -> enum type).

but beware - there is no .TryParse for enums, so you WILL need a try/catch block around the parse to catch failures.

Comment: Wasn't before this question was asked, but now there is as of .NET 4! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.tryparse.aspx.  It would be something like Enum.TryParse<MyColour>( "Red", out color )

Answer (score 0):

```
class EnumStringToInt // to search for a string in enum
{
    enum Numbers{one,two,hree};
    static void Main()
    {
        Numbers num = Numbers.one; // converting enum to string
        string str = num.ToString();
        //Console.WriteLine(str);
        string str1 = "four";
        string[] getnames = (string[])Enum.GetNames(typeof(Numbers));
        int[] getnum = (int[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Numbers));
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= getnum.Length; i++)
            {
                if (str1.Equals(getnames[i]))
                {
                    Numbers num1 = (Numbers)Enum.Parse(typeof(Numbers), str1);
                    Console.WriteLine("string found:{0}", num1);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Value not found!", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: C# has built-in functionality for this.

Comment: how is this an answer to the question? look at the other answers for much easier code

Answer (score 0):

One thing that might be useful to you (besides the already valid/good answers provided so far) is the StringEnum idea provided [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/StringEnum.aspx?msg=2457746)

With this you can define your enumerations as classes (the examples are in vb.net):

> < StringEnumRegisteredOnly(), DebuggerStepThrough(),
>   ImmutableObject(True)> Public NotInheritable Class
>   eAuthenticationMethod    Inherits StringEnumBase(Of
>   eAuthenticationMethod)
>
> ```
> Private Sub New(ByVal StrValue As String)
>   MyBase.New(StrValue)   
> End Sub
>
> < Description("Use User Password Authentication")> Public Shared ReadOnly UsernamePassword As New eAuthenticationMethod("UP")   
>
> < Description("Use Windows Authentication")> Public Shared ReadOnly WindowsAuthentication As New eAuthenticationMethod("W")
> ```
>
> End Class

And now you could use the this class as you would use an enum: eAuthenticationMethod.WindowsAuthentication and this would be essentially like assigning the '**W**' the logical value of **WindowsAuthentication** (inside the enum) and if you were to view this value from a properties window (or something else that uses the System.ComponentModel.Description property) you would get "**Use Windows Authentication**".

I've been using this for a long time now and it makes the code more clear in intent.

Answer (score 0):

```
(MyColours)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyColours), "red", true); // MyColours.Red
(int)((MyColours)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyColours), "red", true)); // 0
```

Answer (score -1):

You might also want to check out some of the suggestions in this blog post:
[My new little friend, Enum<T>](http://devlicious.com/blogs/christopher_bennage/archive/2007/09/13/my-new-little-friend-enum-lt-t-gt.aspx)

The post describes a way to create a very simple generic helper class which enables you to avoid the ugly casting syntax inherent with `Enum.Parse` - instead you end up writing something like this in your code:

```
MyColours colour = Enum<MyColours>.Parse(stringValue);
```

Or check out some of the comments in the same post which talk about using an extension method to achieve similar.

Comment: The post link is broken.