# XNA setting Color by String

Tags: c#, function, xna

So i want to make a function where you put in a color (like White, Red, Aquamarine, etc) and it sets the color of the rectangle to the color you have putten in. What is the best way to do this?

I got this:

```
public void setVisible(GraphicsDevice gd ,SpriteBatch sb, object c) {

        rec = new Rectangle(ButtonXPosition,ButtonYPosition,ButtonWidthSize,ButtonHeightSize);
        Texture2D pixel = new Texture2D(gd, ButtonWidthSize,ButtonHeightSize);
        sb.Draw(pixel,rec,Color.c);
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290262/search-for-a-string-in-enum-and-return-the-enum

Here you go.

Comment: @RyanBennett [XNA Color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.color_members%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx) is not an enum, it is a struct with static properties representing preset values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can retrieve the preset colors by name with a bit of reflection:

```
var prop = typeof(Color).GetProperty(nameOfColor);
if (prop != null)
    return (Color)prop.GetValue(null, null);
return default(Color);
```

Comment: It is worth noting that this will also happily get properties like `R` and `A` and `PackedValue` ;)

Comment: Well, you have to leave something as an exercise for the reader!