# c# combine code with string

Tags: c#, string

i am wondering how to combine code + int/string

example.

```
string USERINPUT = Console.ReadLine();
Console.ForgroundColor = ConsoleColor.USERINPUT
```

but that does not work. how to i wonder?

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: I think the errors are pretty clear, even without the compiler output.

Comment: system.consoleColor does not contain the definition for USERINPUT

Comment: @Inisheer Too many assumptions left to be had, I think. Others are free to guess.

Comment: 3 syntax errors in one line. `console` -> `Console` ; `forgroundcolor` -> `ForegroundColor` ; `consoleColor` -> `ConsoleColor`

Comment: I have the solution, thanks to Eric J. i thank you all for helping me.

Comment: Even though there were typos in the question, it is still a valid question that could be salvaged with a few simple edits.

Comment: @EricJ. I agree, however, I felt editing the syntax used in the original question may significantly take away from the original meaning / issue.

Comment: and the typos were a quick written code. it was never used in C# and i was not checking for spelling. just menting to let you people know what i ment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I Convert a string to an enum in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-c)

Comment: @nawfal thank you for telling me since this questions isnt more than 1 year old...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the assignment

```
Console.ForegroundColor = (something here);
```

you must assign a [ConsoleColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolecolor.aspx), which is an enum.

You can parse an enum value from it's string equivalent.

```
Console.ForegroundColor = 
    (ConsoleColor)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(ConsoleColor), USERINPUT);
```

For details see:

[Search for a string in Enum and return the Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290262/search-for-a-string-in-enum-and-return-the-enum)

Note that my code does not include error handling.  If the user types in a string at the console that is not a member of `ConsoleColor`, you will get an error condition.

Comment: I understand, and i thank you for the help. this was exactly what i was asking for. now i just need to understand what happened in the code. but that will be on my own. i thank you again.