# "Class of <T> where T : Enum" not working

Tags: c#, class, templates, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create Generic method constraining T to an Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum)

Is there any reason why we can't do this in C#? And, if possible, how can I do something similar!

What I want :

```
public class<T> ATag where T : enum {
    [Some code ..]
}

public class<T> classBase where T : enum {
    public IDictionary<T, string> tags { get; set; }
}
```

So, when it comes the time to call it, I'm sur to get only one of my enum values.

```
public class AClassUsingTag : classBase<PossibleTags> {
    public void AMethod(){
         this.tags.Add(PossibleTags.Tag1, "Hello World!");
         this.tags.Add(PossibleTags.Tag2, "Hello Android!");
    }
}

public enum PossibleTags {
    Tag1, Tag2, Tag3
}
```

Error message : `"Constraint cannot be special class 'System.Enum'"`

Thank you!

Comment: It is not possible. Have a look here for a work around: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum

Comment: By the way, the specification is delightful and illuminating reading. Every C# programmer should be familiar with it, and it should be your first source when you have a question about the language. cf. 10.1.5, in particular, for this question.

Comment: @Jason: Yup, and the C# 4 Annotated Spec is particularly wonderful. And I'm not just saying that because I contributed annotations - all the *other* annotations are really interesting :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I agree, all the annotations are insightful.

Comment: @Jon:  Is there a newer version of the C# Annotated Standard book available?  I could not find it.

Comment: @Chris: Newer than which version? I was referring to this one: http://www.amazon.com/dp/0321741765

Comment: Oups sorry... my english not realy good so I didn't find any question related to this before asking it. Hum, sorry but thanks for answerin' it!

Comment: @Jon: Thanks, I was referring to this one: http://www.amazon.com/dp/0123725119 and that's what I was searching for.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can't do it because the spec says you can't, basically. It's annoying, but that's the way it is. The CLR supports it with no problem. My *guess* is that when generics were first being designed, the CLR might *not* have supported it, so it was prohibited in the language too... and either the C# team didn't get the memo about it then being supported, or it was too late too include it. Delegates are similarly annoying.

As for a workaround... have a look at my [Unconstrained Melody](https://github.com/jskeet/unconstrained-melody) project. You could use the same approach yourself. I wrote a [blog post](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/09/10/generic-constraints-for-enums-and-delegates/) at the same time, which goes into more details.

Comment: Do you think this sort of issue is likely to be resolved with Roslyn?

Comment: @series0ne: It's not in the feature list for C# 6 as far as I'm aware... though it may make it easier to do. (It could be easy to hack the check out of Roslyn, too...)

Comment: I was trying a method found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16104/2218697) to convert `string` to `Enum` , One the Comments says to add  `where T : struct` for the extension method to work. But why is it necessary ? Is it syntax for [Enum.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991317(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: @stom: Yes - you can only call `Enum.TryParse<TEnum>` when `TEnum` is known to be a value type due to the constraint on it; if you're calling it from your own generic method, you need the same constraint to ensure that it's a value type.

Comment: ok here is a [method](https://pastebin.com/raw/BqkhP4hz) , which has a constraint  `where T : int` and `int` is a value type , But I get compile time Error, Why?  `'int' is not a valid constraint. A type used as a constraint must be an interface, a non-sealed class or a type parameter`

Comment: @stom: You should ask a new question at this point, as it's really not relevant to this answer. But basically the compiler is telling you what I'd tell you - that constraint is invalid. (How would it be useful anyway? If `int` is the only type you can use, it's not really generic any more...)

Comment: Now possible! Found it at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8086788

Answer (score 6):

it's not possible. But if you are interested in a runtime check you can do

```
class A<T>
        {
            static A()
            {
                if(!typeof(T).IsEnum)
                {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

No I don't believe so.  Yes use a design pattern to get around it, have the base class return the type that's allowed, and the derived classes can check for it.

HTH.