# Enum.Parse fails to cast string

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, enums

I'm trying to load some AppSettings into an object. The settings look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Logging_default_path" value="C:\Temp" />
    <add key="Logging_max_file_size" value="10485760" />
    <add key="Logging_levels" value="Error,Warning,Info"/>
    <add key="Logging_filename" value="RobinsonLog" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

The **Logging_levels**  represents several enum values that are allowed by the settings. I'm trying to load these into my object by using the following code:

```
Level = (LogLevel)Enum.Parse(typeof(LogLevel), settings["Logging_levels"]);
```

But this is not working and I'm only getting LogLevel.Info returned, not the value of Loglevel.Error | LogLevel.Warning | LogLevel.Info. The enum is defined as followed:

```
[Flags]
public enum LogLevel
{
    Error = 0x0,
    Warning = 0x1,
    Info = 0x2,
    Debug = 0x3,
    Performance = 0x4
}
```

Am I wrong by defining the values in hex? or did I miss something else?

Comment: Have you tried creating an enum with your expected value and converting this to string? This should show the proper syntax.

Comment: Your flags values are wrong. The way it's written `Warning | Info == Debug` and `Debug == Debug | Error`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `enum` values are going to cause problems.

The values of a `Flags` `enum` must be powers of two, and you shouldn't use 0 for any value other than some kind of empty/none/nothing indicator.

Does this make any difference?

```
[Flags]
public enum LogLevel
{
    None        =  0
    Error       =  1,
    Warning     =  2,
    Info        =  4,
    Debug       =  8,
    Performance = 16
}
```

Comment: This did the trick. Seems the hex values are indeed not appreciated by the parser.

Comment: Technically, they don't *have to be* powers of two. For example, `[Flags] enum FooBar { Foo = 5, Bar = 10 }` would work correctly too. But doing that would be completely unnecessary complication. There is no reason not to use powers of two.

Comment: @NekoNova, it's not about using hex or decimal. It's about specifying the correct values.

Comment: @NekoNova: It's nothing to do with whether or not the value literals are written in hex. The values must be *powers of two*. It will work exacly the same if you declare them as `0x00`, `0x01`, `0x02`, `0x04`, `0x08`, and `0x10`.

Answer (score 4):

Proper flag values might help (each value should set a different bit):

```
[Flags]
public enum LogLevel
{
    None = 0x0,
    Error = 0x1,
    Warning = 0x2,
    Info = 0x4,
    Debug = 0x8,
    Performance = 0x10
}
```

Note: you can remove the 'None' if you wish.

Answer (score 3):

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx
>
> The value parameter contains the string representation of an enumeration member's underlying value or named constant, or a list of named constants delimited by commas (,). One or more blank spaces can precede or follow each value, name, or comma in value. If value is a list, the return value is the value of the specified names combined with a bitwise OR operation.

So it should work, and ik looks like it does:

```
LogLevel level = (LogLevel)Enum.Parse(typeof(LogLevel), "Error,Warning");

if ((level & LogLevel.Error) == LogLevel.Error)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error");
}

if ((level & LogLevel.Warning) == LogLevel.Warning)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Warning");
}

if ((level & LogLevel.Info) == LogLevel.Info)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Info");
}
```

Gives me "Error" and "Warning". However, by inspecting the `level` variable in Visual Studio, it only shows "Warning". Perhaps that set you off. ;-)

---

Edit: @svick and @jv42 are right, it are your flag values that are wrong.

Comment: debug reports correct value. it's the incorrect value of the flags that causes the problem

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't the parsing! The problem is the conversion to text, instead. Because the flag values aren't distinct bit masks, there is no *deterministic* mapping to string and back. As mentioned by others, you should choose the values like e.g.:

```
[Flags]
public enum LogLevel
{
    None = 0
    Error = 1 << 0,
    Warning = 1 << 1,
    Info = 1 << 2,
    // etc
}
```

See [MSDN: Parsing Enumeration Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.aspx#Parsing)

See a demo live: **https://ideone.com/8AkSQ**

```
using System;

[Flags] enum Colors { None=0, Red = 1, Green = 2, Blue = 4 };

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string[] colorStrings = { "0", "2", "8", "blue", "Blue", "Yellow", "Red, Green" };
      foreach (string colorString in colorStrings)
      {
         try {
            Colors colorValue = (Colors) Enum.Parse(typeof(Colors), colorString);        
            if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Colors), colorValue) | colorValue.ToString().Contains(","))  
               Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", colorString, colorValue.ToString());
            else
               Console.WriteLine("{0} is not an underlying value of the Colors enumeration.", colorString);
         }
         catch (ArgumentException) {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is not a member of the Colors enumeration.", colorString);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
Converted '0' to None.
Converted '2' to Green.
8 is not an underlying value of the Colors enumeration.
'blue' is not a member of the Colors enumeration.
Converted 'Blue' to Blue.
'Yellow' is not a member of the Colors enumeration.
Converted 'Red, Green' to Red, Green.
```

#### Performance Note:

If performance is important, do **not** rely on Enum.Parse :)

See [How should I convert a string to an enum in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-c/38711#38711)

Comment: According to [the doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), parsing flags is supported at least since .Net 2.0.

Comment: Read that article, and I have the flags attribute, but it does not explain how to parse a string into a collection of flags

Comment: The sample says: `Converted 'Red, Green' to Red, Green`. Do you want to get a collection of flags from the combined value? That has _zero_ to do with parsing

Comment: your code does not perform what I intended. I can parse single values without problems, its the combination of values that cuases the problem

Comment: @NekoNova: ah, the flags values should be non-overlapping to do what you expect too, as mentioned by other, notably svick!

Comment: yes, but I thought those hex values would have been fine, but seems it wasn't.... :S
Sometimes I make it so complex for myself...