# 513 Error Code (exit code) FxCop using C#

Tags: c#, fxcop, exit-code, error-code, fxcopcmd

I have VS2010, Windows 7 bits, FxCop 10.0

I execute Fxcopcmd.exe using Process.Start, and I get 513 **"exitcode"** (error code) value.

Todd King in below reference says:

> In this case an exit code of 513 means FxCop had an Analysis Error
>   (0x01) and an assembly references error (0x200)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstscode/thread/1191af28-d262-4e4f-95d9-73b682c2044c/

I think if it is like

```
    [Flags]
    public enum FxCopErrorCodes
    {
        NoErrors = 0x0,
        AnalysisError = 0x1,  // -fatalerror
        RuleExceptions = 0x2,
        ProjectLoadError = 0x4,
        AssemblyLoadError = 0x8,
        RuleLibraryLoadError = 0x10,
        ImportReportLoadError = 0x20,
        OutputError = 0x40,
        CommandlineSwitchError = 0x80,
        InitializationError = 0x100,
        AssemblyReferencesError = 0x200,
        BuildBreakingMessage = 0x400,
        UnknownError = 0x1000000,
    }
```

513 integer value is 0x201 (view [int to hex string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690480/int-to-hex-string) and [Enum.Parse fails to cast string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242875/enum-parse-fails-to-cast-string) )

How can I know errors (Analysis Error (0x01) and an assembly references error (0x200)) programmatically using only exitcode (513 , 0x201) value ?

More about Error Codes for FxCopCmd and Code Analysis:

- http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164705(VS.80).aspx
- http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245349(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Maybe useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/5655038/206730

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test for a specific value of your enum using a AND bitwise operation:

```
FxCopErrorCodes code = (FxCopErrorCodes)0x201;
if ((code & FxCopErrorCodes.InitializationError) == FxCopErrorCodes.InitializationError)
{
    Console.WriteLine("InitializationError");
}
```

You could get the whole list of values using something like:

```
private static IEnumerable<FxCopErrorCodes> GetMatchingValues(FxCopErrorCodes enumValue)
{
    // Special case for 0, as it always match using the bitwise AND operation
    if (enumValue == 0)
    {
        yield return FxCopErrorCodes.NoErrors;
    }

    // Gets list of possible values for the enum
    var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(FxCopErrorCodes)).Cast<FxCopErrorCodes>();

    // Iterates over values and return those that match
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        if (value > 0 && (enumValue & value) == value)
        {
            yield return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Kiquenet It works with 3.5 and above. You'll have to add `using System.Linq;`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.90).aspx