# Cannot convert string to enum

Tags: c#, enums

I need to make an adapter class.

trip.Resource is an enum named ModalityResource.

transportOrderTrip.ModalityResource is a string.

```
if(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(ModalityResource), transportOrderTrip.ModalityResource))
    trip.Resource = Enum.Parse(typeof(ModalityResource), transportOrderTrip.ModalityResource, true);
```

Possible values for ModalityResource here:

```
 public enum ModalityResource { NONE, CHASSIS, TRAILER }
```

The error i get is this one: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'ModalityResource'. Anyone might know what is wrong?

Edit: Never mind, was bit confused.

```
  trip.Resource = (ModalityResource) Enum.Parse(typeof (Shared.Interfaces.ModalityResource), transportOrderTrip.ModalityResource, true);
```

Comment: You should still accept an answer even if you figured it out yourself - then write an answer yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to cast the result of `Enum.Parse` as `ModalityResource`.
In .NET 4 or newer you can also use the generic overloads of the function.

```
trip.Resource = (ModalityResource)Enum.Parse(typeof(ModalityResource), transportOrderTrip.ModalityResource, true);
```

#### See also

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need as cast.

```
Enum.Parse method returns object
```

change your code to following

```
(ModalityResource)Enum.Parse(typeof(ModalityResource), transportOrderTrip.ModalityResource, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you would need to cast it to the required `Enum` type as the return type is `object`

```
(ModalityResource) Enum.Parse(typeof(ModalityResource), 
                             transportOrderTrip.ModalityResource, true);
```

On [Why object is returned instead of an enum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324883/why-does-enum-parse-return-object)