# Convert from String to Enum return not valid cast in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, enums

I trying to convert from WPF combobox selected value to enumurator it return not valid cast in the runtime otherwise the string and the enum name is matched my code is

```
Siren.PfundMemberWebServices.Emirates EM = (Siren.PfundMemberWebServices.Emirates)cmbemirate.SelectedValue
```

Comment: What is the type of selected value ?

Comment: What is the type of selected object is String

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-c - So after defining the problem - we can see it is duplicated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert a string to an `enum` you need to use [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Siren.PfundMemberWebServices.Emirates EM = (Siren.PfundMemberWebServices.Emirates)Enum.Parse(typeof(Siren.PfundMemberWebServices.Emirates), cmbemirate.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: Need `typeof(Siren.PfundMemberWebServices.Emirates)` for the first parameter of `Parse()`

Comment: @MatthewWatson - thanks. I changed it just before your comment!

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not complete but the [InvalidCastException](http://www.dotnetperls.com/invalidcastexception) occurs when an explicit cast is applied. But the type is not in the same path of the type hierarchy. The cast does not succeed.

Use:

```
Siren.PfundMemberWebServices.Emirates EM = (Siren.PfundMemberWebServices.Emirates)Enum.Parse(typeof(Siren.PfundMemberWebServices.Emirates), cmbemirate.SelectedValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have int values with combobox then you can try:

```
Siren.PfundMemberWebServices.Emirates EM = (Siren.PfundMemberWebServices.Emirates)Convert.ToInt32(cmbemirate.SelectedValue)
```