# How to convert an object collection to an array of Enum

Tags: c#, enums

I seem to be stuck trying to convert a collection of ListBox items to Enum.

Here is my code

```
 ChannelCodeType[] ChannelCodes = lbSearch.SelectedItems;


public enum ChannelCodeType {

        /// <remarks/>
        XYZ1,

        /// <remarks/>
        XYZ1_KIDS,

        /// <remarks/>
        XYZ1_PRIME,

        /// <remarks/>
        XYZ13,

        /// <remarks/>
        XYZ14,
    }
```

I am trying to pass the values (selecteditems) back to the ChannelCodes

Comment: The way you put this makes no sense. You want to set an array of an `enum` type to a set of values from a dropdown of some sort. You don't want to pass anything to an enum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `SelectedItems` property is most likely a collection of type `Object`.

Try casting the collection back to the original type:

```
ChannelCodeType[] ChannelCodes
    = lbSearch.SelectedItems.Cast<ChannelCodeType>().ToArray();
```

I'm assuming `lbSearch` is a ListBox and that it's been filled with `ChannelCodeType` values.

---

If Baldrick is right, and you've got string representations of the `ChannelCodeType` enum values, then you may need to modify the code to parse the strings back to the original enum:

```
ChannelCodeType[] ChannelCodes
  = lbSearch.SelectedItems
            .Cast<string>()
            .Select(c => (ChannelCodeType)Enum.Parse(typeof(ChannelCodeType), c))
            .ToArray();
```

Comment: If I had to *guess*, I'd suggest the OP *might* have the string representations of the enum as the underlying object in the ListBox. In which case, you'd need to do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-c

Comment: @GrantWinney, i missed the cast and try to pass the value,that's why it keeps complaining. thanks a lot Grant Winney.