# How to Convert DaysOfWeek Array to a Enum?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2010, enums, exchangewebservices

iam getting from EWS an WeeklyPattern with DaysOfTheWeek. It's in an Array an can be one day or Multiple.

I have an Enum which is called DayOfWeekMask and i need to convert the Array to the Enum.

When the Weeklypatter contains "Monday,Tuesday"

The function should return:

```
return DayOfWeekMask.olMonday | DayOfWeekMask.olThursday ;
```

when the weeklypatter contains 3 days it should return 3 elements.

is this possible?

Comment: does `WeeklyPattern` contain 1 string delimited by `,` or a list of strings?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I Convert a string to an enum in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-c)

Comment: @BCdotWEB I don't think this is a duplicate. They are two different questions.

Comment: Potential duplicate of [What does the \[Flags\] Enum Attribute mean in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c). more Reading [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.FlagsAttribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @BerndLinde That is not a duplicate.  That explains the flags attribute for an enum.  This is asking about converting a list of enum names into a single value of an enum.

Comment: @juharr noticed that as well after I submitted the flag (But still a good read for this case). Waiting on the OP to say what the array is to write up an answer

Comment: [Recurrence.WeeklyPattern.DaysOfTheWeek](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.recurrence.weeklypattern.daysoftheweek(v=exchg.80).aspx) is a [DayOfTheWeekCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.dayoftheweekcollection(v=exchg.80).aspx). This collection contains [DayOfTheWeek](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.dayoftheweek(v=exchg.80).aspx) enum items. So most likely they can be converted to your custom `DayOfWeekMask` enum.

Comment: I understand that WeeklyPattern.DaysOfTheWeek( cf. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.recurrence.weeklypattern.daysoftheweek%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) is not an array of strings but a collection of enums.

Comment: @GrantWinney is it this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.recurrencepattern.dayofweekmask.aspx?

Comment: Eray, read the documentation properly, write sample code and ask again. With a minimal self contained example. Obtaining the necessary information is the first step in programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names in both enums are very similar (`OlDaysOfWeek` just appends "ol" to the beginning of the name), so we can take advantage of that.

This converts the [`DaysOfTheWeek`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.recurrence.weeklypattern.daysoftheweek(v=exchg.80).aspx) property (a collection of `DayOfTheWeek` values) to [`OlDaysOfWeek`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.oldaysofweek.aspx) (the type on the [`DayOfWeekMask`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.recurrencepattern.dayofweekmask.aspx) property), which seems to be what you're asking for:

```
OlDaysOfWeek daysOfTheWeek =
    weeklyPattern.DaysOfTheWeek
                 .Select(x => (OlDaysOfWeek) Enum.Parse(typeof (OlDaysOfWeek), "ol" + x))
                 .Aggregate((x, y) => x | y);
```

If your initial collection includes `DayOfTheWeek.Tuesday` and `DayOfTheWeek.Thursday`, this will output a value equivalent to `OlDaysOfWeek.olTuesday | OlDaysOfWeek.olThursday`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a string formatted as a comma-separated list of days:

```
"Monday, Tuesday, Thursday"
```

You can `Split` it into a string array and parse each element:

```
var days = weekString.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

DayOfWeekMask? result = null;

foreach (var day in days) {
    var enumDayName = "ol" + day;
    if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(DayOfWeekMask), enumDayName)) {
        result |= (DayOfWeekMask)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeekMask), enumDayName, true);
    }
}
```

Note that you need to define values for each element of `DayOfWeekMask` to make the ORing work properly!

If your input is a `DayOfTheWeekCollection`, then you can just directly convert the Enum values:

```
DayOfTheWeekCollection days;  // get this from somewhere

foreach (var day in days) {
    switch (day) {
        case DayOfTheWeek.Monday:
            result |= DayOfWeekMask.Monday;
            break;
        case DayOfTheWeek.Tuesday:
            // etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the WeeklyPattern.DaysOfTheWeek documentation?

Comment: I'm familiar with it, but he said his weekly pattern is "Monday, Tuesday"....if it's the DayOfWeekCollection, that's different...

Comment: I think the OP has no clue (that is, he didn't show evidence of any) and is mistaken wrt to the data he gets.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact format of your variables, but something along these lines:

```
return (WeeklyPattern.Contains( "Monday") ? DayOfWeekMask.olMonday : 0)
  | (WeeklyPattern.Contains( "Tuesday") ? DayOfWeekMask.olTuesday : 0)
  | (WeeklyPattern.Contains( "Wednesday") ? DayOfWeekMask.olWednesday : 0)
  | (WeeklyPattern.Contains( "Thursday") ? DayOfWeekMask.olThursday : 0)
  | (WeeklyPattern.Contains( "Friday") ? DayOfWeekMask.olFriday : 0);
```