# Convert ENUM to int using CsvHelper

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I'm using CsvHelper to write into csv file.
I want to write ENUM as `int`, not `string`.

What is the eassiesest way to do this?
Assuming I have some types of `ENUM`'s, not just one.

```
    public enum EStatus
    {
        ES_FAILED = 0,
        ES_DONE,
        ES_UNKNOWN
    }

Map(m => m.status).Index(0)
```

**output:**

```
ES_DONE
```

**Expected:**

```
1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use EnumConverter with CsvHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31666915/how-to-use-enumconverter-with-csvhelper)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it.

```cs
Map(m => m.Status).Index(0).ConvertUsing(row => ((int)row.Status).ToString());
```