# What is the best way to strictly parse string to enum?

Tags: c#, enums

Let's say I have an enum:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    OptionOne = 0,
    OptionTwo = 2,
    OptionThree = 4
}
```

Like it was said in the [How should I convert a string to an enum in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-c) question, I parse enum from string, using `Enum.Parse` method:

```
public class Enumer
{
    public static MyEnum? ParseEnum(string input)
    {
        try
        {
            return (MyEnum) Enum.Parse(typeof (MyEnum), input);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work as expected with integer numbers, represented as strings.
**I do not expect Parse.Enum() to convert int from string, but actually it does.**
A simple test:

```
[TestClass]
public class Tester
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestEnum()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(MyEnum.OptionTwo, Enumer.ParseEnum("OptionTwo"));
        Assert.IsNull(Enumer.ParseEnum("WrongString"));
        Assert.IsNull(Enumer.ParseEnum("2")); // returns 2 instead of null
        Assert.IsNull(Enumer.ParseEnum("12345")); // returns 12345 instead of null
    }
}
```

Only two checks of four can be passed.
`Enumer.ParseEnum("2")` returns `MyEnum.OptionTwo` instead of `null`.
Moreover, `Enumer.ParseEnum("12345")` returns 12345, regardless it's out of the scope.

What is the best way to parse:

1. Only string values of "MyEnum.OptionOne", "MyEnum.OptionTwo", "MyEnum.OptionThree" into their enum counterparts.
2. Strings "MyEnum.OptionOne", "MyEnum.OptionTwo", "MyEnum.OptionThree" AND the values of 0, 2 and 4 into MyEnum.OptionOne, MyEnum.OptionTwo, MyEnum.OptionThree respectively?

The link to the similar question [How should I convert a string to an enum in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-c) doesn't help with the test provided - it still converts strings as integers, even when they are out of the enum scope.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a string to an enum in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-c)

Comment: @ErkanDemirel, as far as I understand, that question was about Enum.Parse() syntax itself.

Comment: @Kolky you've misunderstood the question. I do NOT want to parse "12345" as 12345, but Enum.Parse does it.

Comment: I feel like you didn't read the post.

Comment: Sorry, misread your last statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this yourself using `Enum.GetValues(Type enumType)`.

```
public static MyEnum? ParseEnum(string input)
{
    return (MyEnum?) Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).OfType<object>()
                         .FirstOrDefault(v => v.ToString() == input);
}
```

Adding support for integers you can also add.

```
public static MyEnum? ParseEnum(string input)
{
    int value;
    var isInt = int.TryParse(input, out value);
    return (MyEnum?) Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).OfType<object>()
                         .FirstOrDefault(v => v.ToString() == input
                                           || (isInt & (int)v == value));
}
```

Since I am not 100% sure about your last requirements I add one that includes the name as well and is more generic

```
public static T? ParseEnum<T>(string input)
    where T : struct 
{
    int value;
    var isInt = int.TryParse(input, out value);
    return (T?)Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).OfType<object>()
                   .FirstOrDefault(v => v.ToString() == typeof(T).Name + input
                                    || (isInt & (int)v == value));
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient first convert into the enum and then check the scope?

Comment: AFAIK the enum methods `Parse()` and `IsDefined()` use reflection since an enum is nothing else than a class with `public const int OptionOne = 1` fields. Therefore this should have identical performance. If you want to do this efficiently you should create a `IDictionary<string, MyEnum>` and `IDictionary<int, MyEnum>` and use this for the conversion.