# Use dynamic keys in keydownevent

Tags: c#, dynamic, switch-statement, keydown

I'm doing a little C# program, but it is configurable.  `Properties.Settings.Default.foobar` is equal to `F3`, but that is subject to change.  Originally it'd be this way:

```
case Keys.F3:
    //dostuff
break;
```

But I need `Properties.Settings.Default.foobar` in place of `F3`, since it's a setting and thus subject to change.

```
case Keys.Properties.Settings.Default.foobar:
```

Obviously doesn't work, nor does putting it in parenthesis, so I'm not sure.  I'm clearly new to C#, so any help?

The program uses unfocused hotkeys, but these keys are user configurable, so I can't have any sort of constant/static for a case, right?

Comment: When you say "obviously doesn't work", what is the exact error?

Comment: Not exact, but "properties" is not in "keys".  I'd think a parenthesis would work, but I guess not.

Comment: What exactly is stored in `foobar`? A string like "F3"?

Comment: Yes it's a string.  Need I convert it to a char?

Answer (score 1):

```
case Keys.Properties.Settings.Default.foobar:
```

As you say, this obviously doesn't work. The specific reason is that the values for a `case` statement must be compile-time constants.

A simpler `if` comparison would probably be better. Since your value is a `Keys` and your property is a `string`, you'll need to convert one type to the other for comparison. I'll convert to a string for simplicity, or you could [convert the string to the enum type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-c).

```
if (myVar.ToString() == Properties.Settings.Default.foobar)
```

So instead of having, e.g.

```
switch (myVar) {
    case Keys.F1:
        // something
    case Keys.F2:
        // something
}
```

You would have:

```
if (myVar.ToString() == Properties.Settings.Default.foo) {
    // something
} else if (myVar.ToString() == Properties.Settings.Default.bar) {
    // something
}
```

Comment: Could you add an example of how I would use this in this situation?

Comment: @coltonon I've added an example.

Comment: @coltonon Also, I realized I had a mistake in my code until now: You can't do `Keys.Parse` directly. Converting to enums is a little more complicated than that. I linked to a question that has answers on how you can do that conversion, if you want to go that route (and I'm sure you will at some point, if not for this particular problem).

Answer (score 0):

`Keys.F3` is a value of the [`Keys`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx) enumeration. So you'll need to convert your `Properties.Settings.Default.foobar` string into a value of the enumeration too.

Luckily, there is a built-in method to do that:

```
var foobarKey = (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), Properties.Settings.Default.foobar);
...
if (whatever == foobarKey)
{
    ...
```

Comment: This isn't working, as VS is telling me a constant is needed.  The answer below seems to add more to it...

Comment: Ah, you'll need to use `if` instead of `case`, as the other answer mentions. Edited.