# How to Set a Control's Property Using a String Variable in C# XAML WinRT?

Tags: c#, xaml, variables, properties, windows-runtime

### How can I set the property for a XAML control using a string variable?

This is an example of the variable to be used.

```
string imageStretch = "Uniform";
```

How can it be set like this programmatically in the code behind?

```
myImage.Stretch = imageStretch;
```

The reason is that I would like to avoid using a long chunk of code like this.

```
if (imageStretch == "None") { myImage.Stretch = Stretch.None; }
if (imageStretch == "Fill") { myImage.Stretch = Stretch.Fill; }
if (imageStretch == "Uniform") { myImage.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform; }
if (imageStretch == "UniformToFill") { myImage.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill; }
```

If this can be done, can it be done for other types of controls/properties as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a string to an enum in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use enum.Parse() like such...

```
myImage.Stretch = (Stretch)Enum.Parse(typeof(Stretch), imageStretch);
```