# Cast dictionary content to type - enum datatype

Tags: c#, enums

In C#, I have the enum data type:

```
public enum DebugLevel
{
    NONE = 0,
    ERROR = 1,
    ...
}
```

inside an object:

```
public class DataOptions
{
    #region Fields
    public DebugLevel debug = DebugLevel.NONE;
    ...
```

and the data is provided via POST in a FormData as an int:

```
Form Data:
    debug: 0
```

and is then parsed in a WebAPI like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public AjaxAnswer<SomeDataType[]> MyEndpoint(HttpRequestMessage req) {
    DataOptions o = null;
    try
    {
        o = req.DecodeJSON<DataOptions>();
    }
    catch (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException) // Not JSON - old frontend versions are sending as form data
    {
        try { 
            o = req.DecodeFormData<DataOptions>();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return new AjaxAnswer<SomeDataType[]>() {success:false, data:new SomeDataType[0], Error: "Error in MyEndpoint", ErrorMessage: "Could not decode request payload: " + e.Message
        }
}
```

DecodeFormData is a custom Extension Method which looks like this:

```
public static T DecodeFormData<T>(this System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage req) where T : new()
{
    string postdata = req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    Dictionary<string, string> s = postdata.Split('&').Where(x=>x.Contains('=')).Select(x => x.Split('=')).ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(x[1]));

    return s.ToType<T>();
}
```

For some reason, this code throws the error:

> Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'MyNamespace.DebugLevel'

Conversions without that `enum` run through fine. What is happening there (behind the `s.ToType<T>()` line) and why?

Comment: Can you add `postdata` also.

Comment: wheres the `.ToType` method coming from?

Answer (score 4):

To convert a `string` to an enum, use `Enum.Parse(...)`.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-c) for more info.