# C# Changing the method I call based on a string

Tags: c#

First of all sorry if this is a duplicate. I dont exactly know how to search for this.

I have a question about how to be able to use a saved string to change what type of method I call

```
MenuBar.Dock = Dockstyle.DockStyleString //DockStyleString is a string defined somewhere with either Top or Bottom
```

Comment: Write code that does that. Use chained [if/else if/else](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else) statements, or a [switch statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch). You'll have to write this code yourself. Try something and if it doesn't work, we'll help you get it working. But we won't write the code for you.

Comment: Your question is insufficient. Please provide more information, detailing what you expect to be able to do, and an example of code that you have tried which does not work.

Comment: `if (menuBar.Dock == "Bottom") Dothis(); else DoSomeThingelse(); ` There´s not much we can do as you´re not providing enough information. So any answer you´ll get is vague.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you give us more information about the problem? It's not easy to understand what you want to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I convert a string to an enum in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/how-should-i-convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-c)

Comment: Stop hating on this question. Is a valid question from someone who is starting programming.

Answer (score 2):

So, according to your example you seem to be using an enumerator. Enum has utilities that would 'convert' a string into the right enum value. Also you can have an utility class that does that for you.

```
DockstyleUtils.FromString("DockStyleString");
```

This would return an enum `Dockstyle.DockstyleString`.

So, you can use it `MenuBar.Dock = DockstyleUtils.FromString("DockStyleString");`

I created this method you can use...

```
public DockStyle ConvertDockingStyleFromString(string dockingStyle)
        {
            return (DockStyle)Enum.Parse(typeof(DockStyle), dockingStyle);
        }
```

There you go.

Answer (score 0):

Some of this depends on what you want to do with the string once you have it. You can use the code in @PepitoFernandez's answer to convert it to an enum. If you'd like to then use it to determine what method to call against an object, you have a few options.

The first is that if it's a known set of strings, you could use a `switch` statement:

```
switch (stringVariable) {
    case "stringA": methodA(); break;
    case "stringB": methodB(); break;
    ...
    // If you get a "bad" string, you WANT to throw an exception to make
    // debugging easier
    default: throw new ArgumentException("Method name not recognized");
}
```

Obviously, you can also replace this with enum values if you do the conversion first. (That's actually not a bad idea because if you get a "bad" string you

The other option (if you want to do it dynamically at runtime) is to do the call using reflection, like this:

```
public class SomeClass
    {
        public void MethodA()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MethodA");
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Type type = typeof(SomeClass);
        // Obviously, you'll want to replace the hardcode with your string
        MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("MethodA");

        SomeClass cls = new SomeClass();

        // The second argument is the parameters; I pass null here because
        // there aren't any in this case
        method.Invoke(cls, null);
    }
```