# Why Enum.TryParse requires constraint where T : struct

Tags: c#, struct, enums

I was trying understand a extension  method to convert `string` to `Enum` found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16104/2218697).

```
public static T ToEnum<T>(this string value, T defaultValue)
{
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
     {
        return defaultValue;
     }

     T result;
     return Enum.TryParse<T>(value, true, out result) ? result : defaultValue;
}
```

**Compile Error:**

> The type 'T' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as
>   parameter 'TEnum' in the generic type or method
>   'Enum.TryParse(string, bool, out TEnum)'

One the Comments says to add `where T : struct` for the extension method to work.

**Method With Constraint:**

```
public static T ToEnum<T>(this string value, T defaultValue) where T : struct
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
          return defaultValue;
    }

    T result;
    return Enum.TryParse<T>(value, true, out result) ? result : defaultValue;
}
```

I read the docs on [Enum.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991317(v=vs.110).aspx) , but I don't understand in docs on why `where T : struct` is added as constraint for type T ?

Why would above extension wont work without constraint as `struct` why not other value types ? How to relate `struct` and `Enum` type ? or  Is it just a syntax to follow ?

**Update:**

Most of them said any value type can be used , I tried to use `where T : int` But I get compile time error:

> 'int' is not a valid constraint. A type used as a constraint must be
>   an interface, a non-sealed class or a type parameter.

Comment: This constraint prevents passing types that are certainly not enum types to that method. If it were possible to restrict even more to `where T: Enum` - that would be better, but it's not possible.

Comment: @HimBromBeere , why only `struct` as constraint ? Why not other value types ?

Comment: @stom Which other value types are you talking about?

Comment: Now I see your point, good question. +1

Comment: @Evk , Do You mean `struct` is `Enum` type ?

Comment: @stom No, an *enum* is a *struct* but never a *class* so the best constraint to use is *struct*, because there is no constraint for *enum* which would fit better

Comment: Maybe you are confused by thinking that struct is only type you define with `public struct SomeType {...}`. That's not so - many built-in types are also "structs" (value types), such as int, long, DateTime, Enum and so on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Generic method constraining T to an Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum)

Comment: It is necessary because Enum.TryParse<> has this constraint.  So you can't write "T can be anything" generic code when the method demands "You can only call me when T is a value type".  Fwiw, ideally T would be constrained to be an enum type.  That is however not possible in C#, a tricky problem related to an enum having an underlying type that determines its size.  Size matters a great deal to generic code.

Answer (score 1):

The **constraint** `struct` does not only include types you declared via `struct MyStruct`, but also many built-in-types such as `int`, `byte` or `char`. Actually the constraint restricts `T` to be of any **value-type**, see this from the [C#-specification 9.4.5 Satisfying constraints](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf):

> If the constraint is the value type constraint (struct), the type A shall satisfy one of the following
>
> - A is a struct type or enum type, but not a nullable value type. [Note: System.ValueType and System.Enum are reference types that do
>     not satisfy this constraint. end note]
> - A is a type parameter having the value type constraint (§15.2.5)

Of course it´ll be nice if there were a more restricitve constraint.

As of your edit: your compiler-message is pretty clear in this case. When using a *type* as constraint, you can use only interfaces or non-sealed classed. Restricting a generic type-parameter to match exactly one single class (or struct) would make a *generic* quite useless, wouldn´t it? Restricting your generic to `int` will effectivly turn your method-signature in something like this:

```
public static int ToEnum(this string value, int defaultValue)
```

because there´s only one struct matching the constraint.

Comment: `the constraint restricts T to be of any value-type` , Then why I am not able to use `where T :  int`  ? `int`  is a value type right ?

Comment: `When using a type as constraint, you can use only interfaces or non-sealed classes.`  Where does `struct` comes in this category ?

Comment: @stom Not at all. It´s about a **type**-constraint. not the **value-type**-constraint (see the part from c#-spec). You can write `where T: struct` which allows **all** value-types, or `where T: MyInterface` where `T` is the type-constraint allowing only instances of the interface.

Comment: I have final question , I don't have option to use where T : Enum , because compiler doesn't allow. Ok why does compiler allow `where T : struct` ? isn't  because it belongs to syntax of `Enum.TryParse` ?

Comment: `You can write where T: struct which allows all value-types`, Can you prove that statement by creating a extension method that accepts `int` and converts to `Enum`?

Comment: @stom I can´t see how this would improve the answer in any way. However you can easily try this out on your own.

Answer (score 0):

This is done to enable partial error checking at compile time:

- Reference types are rejected at compile time,
- Value types that are not `enum`s are rejected at runtime.

It would be better if you could write `where T : Enum`, but C# compiler prohibits this:

> A constraint cannot be special class `System.Enum'

For more information on this error [see this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/79126/335858). In particular, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28527552/335858) for a short work-around to the problem.