# Call function1 with function2 arguments

Tags: c#

I'm new to C#, with basic knowledge from other languages. And I came up with this problem:

```
public void startupMessage(string appTitle, string (((color))))
{                                               V--------V
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.(((color)));
}
```

What I think is some of the problem is that the second parameter has to be something else than string. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I convert a string to an enum in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/how-should-i-convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-c)

Comment: Why is `color` a `string` and not a `ConsoleColor`?

Comment: It's best to first read through the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.foregroundcolor(v=vs.110).aspx) before asking

Comment: @GiladGreen Would not know what to look for.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Because I don't want to call startupMessage with ConsoleColor.Blue as a parameter. I just want "Blue". Dmigo answered my question perfectly in his second solution using Enum.Parse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see two possible solutions for the problem:
First is to use `ConsoleColor` as an argument type:

```
public void startupMessage(string appTitle, ConsoleColor color)
{
   Console.ForegroundColor = color;
}
```

Second is to parse the argument:

```
public void startupMessage(string appTitle, string color)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = (ConsoleColor) Enum.Parse(typeof(ConsoleColor), color);
}
```

Comment: Since our answers are basically the same, I've deleted mine and upvoted yours. Seems like you could use the rep more then me.

Comment: I tried to upvote yours @zohar it was first.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Please mark as duplicate instead. No reason to have yet another Enum.Parse duplicate on this site

Comment: Awesome! That worked! Solution 2 is exactly what I wanted to learn! Probably not as much needed for this project, could have easly used solution 1 aswell. But solution 2 answered my question perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate @Camilo there's a choice of argument in parameter or cast string to enum.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto actually, this question is not an exact duplicate. It's unclear from the question alone if the OP wants to parse the enum value from the string or was just wondering what to pass as the color. However, in his comment to my answer, the OP clarified that, so yes, that's the correct duplicate.

Comment: @JeremyThompson The OP mentioned in another answer what they wanted, so it is a duplicate

Comment: @ZoharPeled Then either close as unclear or as duplicate, still no reason to answer.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Please let me decide for myself if I want to answer a question or vote to close. IMHO, There is nothing wrong with answering duplicate questions, and I know that some of the highest ranking members agree with this opinion. Jeff Atwood even [blogged about that.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)