# Using a variable in conjunction with enumerators

Tags: c#, enums

I am using an enumerator in my script, and at the moment it has a very simple enum:

```c#
public enum Item
{
    Wood,
    Stone
}
```

With this enum, I am able to do stuff that you are normally able to do with an enum, such as `int foo = (int)Item.Wood`, which sets `foo` equal to 0. However, there is a point in my script where I want to set an `int` variable using the enum, but I don't know what the item will be. For example:

```c#
public enum Item
{
    Wood,
    Stone
}

string ItemString = "Stone";

int foo = (int)Item.ItemString
```

However, this doesn't work because now the script is looking for an enumeration called ItemString, instead of looking at the value of ItemString and finding the enumeration of that. Anybody know what I can do in this situation? If necessary I can provide more details and clarification.

Edit: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-c-sharp) partially answers my question, but the accepted answer better shows how to implement the answer from the linked post.

Comment: It isn't fully clear, why do you need to cast `string` to `int` here, if you asking about `enum` actually

Comment: Just make a method that compares a string with the ToString of each Item inside the enumerate..

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-c-sharp

Comment: When you use the dot notation, you access the elements/methods of the variable. Item only has wood and stone, you cant call item.<variableName> but you can parse variable value to get enum, as described in the link above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `TryParse`

```
        string ItemString = "Stone";
        Item enumItem;
        Item.TryParse(ItemString, out enumItem);
        int foo = (int)enumItem;
        Console.WriteLine(foo);

public enum Item
{
    Wood,
    Stone
}
```

[you can check the sample code here](https://ideone.com/Y5bNo4)

Comment: I'd get rid of `Item enumItem` and would change to `Item.TryParse(ItemString, out Item enumItem);`

Comment: Also, you don't handle the situation when parsing fails.

Comment: Yes, in case parsing fails, we can set it to -1.

Comment: For me, the way that I have the code set up, I don't have to worry about the parsing failing. When implemented, the `ItemString` variable will always be parsable.