# Cannot implicitly convert type string to Autodesk.Revit.BD.DisplayUnitType

Tags: c#, sql-server, revit-api

I am using `sqlDatareader` to read and assign variable value. The variable datatype is string.

```
string displayUnits = dr["DisplayUnits"].ToString(); // the variable value "DisplayUnitType.DUT_GENERAL"
```

Variable value is used to assign `formatOptions.DisplayUnits`.

```
formatOptions.DisplayUnits = displayUnits;
```

However, I am getting an error message cannot implicitly convert type string to `Autodesk.Revit.BD.DisplayUnitType`. I know I assigned a value to another type.

How do I casting and type conversions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, you cannot implicitly convert a `string` to an `enum`.

You can **explicitly** [convert a string to an enum in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-c-sharp), as Chetan already pointed out.

Comment: Work fine: DisplayUnitType enumDisplayUnits = (DisplayUnitType)Enum.Parse(typeof(DisplayUnitType), displayUnits);