# How to turn 'string' into 'BuiltInCategory' in Revit Python Shell when reading excel file

Tags: python, excel, revit-api, revitpythonshell

I am trying to import data from Excel to Revit Python Shell in order to verify if some parameters exist in the Revit file for selected categories of objects. But I am having some problems in the first 'for' loop (look into the first column of the excel sheet and get the categories).
The first step to achieving what I wanted would be to get all the elements of the categories that I want to analyze. I've tried a lot of things, but I always end up in this error shown in the picture (got string instead of built-in category). I searched for a method to transform a string into builtincategories, but I did not find anything.

Does anyone know how to deal with it? Is there a way to transform a string into built-in category or is there another solution for this?

Thank you!
[picture - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoSkT.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is more a C# than a Revit API one. Search for '[c# enum string convert](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=c%23+enum+string+convert)', which turns up, e.g., [convert a string to an enum in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-c-sharp#16104). In this case:

```
BuiltInCategory bic = BuiltInCategory.Parse( "some_string" );
```

Comment: Thank you for your appreciation. Glad it helped. You can upvote the answer to make it easier to find for others with the same question.

Comment: Actually this didn't work for me, but I managed with:
`BuiltInCategory bic = (BuiltInCategory)Enum.Parse(typeof(BuiltInCategory), categoryString);`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is with these lines:

```
 fec = FilteredElementCollector(doc)
 cat = fec.OfCategory(i.Value2)
```

In this instance, `i.Value2` is a `string`, but `fec.OfCategory` is wanting a `BuiltInCategory` as you've commented earlier.

Jeremy's answer will convert a `string` to a `BuiltInCategory` (thanks Jeremy, I had no idea you could do that!) like this:
`bic = BuiltInCategory.Parse(BuiltInCategory, "OST_PlumbingFixtures")`

So in your example it would be:

`fec.OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.Parse(BuiltInCategory, i.Value2.split('.')[1]))`