# Is it possible to set a custom request method with RestSharp?

Tags: c#, console-application, restsharp

I'm working on a C# console application which calls external REST APIs with RestSharp.

The issue now is that I have to access an API that only allows a custom request method like `FOOBAR` instead of the traditional `GET` or `POST`.

```
using RestSharp;

var request = new RestRequest();
request.Method = Method.POST;
```

Unfortunately, I haven't seen anything pertaining to custom request methods in RestSharp's [docs](https://restsharp.dev/api/RestSharp.html) or GitHub [issues](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues) section.

Keep in mind that I only have a basic knowledge on this, so my trials might be considered silly.

I've tried assigning a string to it but it only accepts an enum.

```
request.Method = "FOOBAR"; // Does not accept strings
```

I've also tried converting a string to enum using code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16104/10783786), but this defaults to a `GET`. It might be like that due to my converted string not being in their enum [Method](https://restsharp.dev/api/restsharp.html).

```
Enum.TryParse("FOOBAR", out Method customRequestMethod);
request.Method = customRequestMethod; // Defaults to GET
```

If this is not possible with RestSharp, is this feature doable with HttpClient or Flurl?

Comment: You should not call that a feature but a misuse. Something with REST in its name should not allow things that aren't anywhere near REST behaviour. HttpClient should allow such a call. You need to use then the SendAsync methods that allow a custom HttpRequestMessage that allow a custom HttpMethod.

Comment: @Ralf alright thank you for the clarification. Will proceed to do more research on HttpClient.