# How to convert string to enum in c# with SelectToken

Tags: c#, string, enums

Please refer to the below-given code snippet

```cs
foreach (var invoiceDescription in qbInvoiceLineArray)
{
    Line lineDescription = new Line();
    lineDescription.Description = Convert.ToString((string)invoiceDescription.SelectToken(QBConfig.InvoiceDescription));
    invoice.Line.Add(lineDescription);             
} 
    
public class QbInvoiceViewModel
{
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }       
    public List<LinkedTxn> LinkedTxn { get; set; }
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime TxnDate { get; set; }
    public Decimal TotalAmt { get; set; }
    public List<Line> Line { get; set; }    
}
    
public class Line
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public LineDetailTypeEnum DetailType { get; set; }
}
    
public enum LineDetailTypeEnum
{
    SalesItemLineDetail
}
```

This line of code

```cs
lineDescription.Description = Convert.ToString((string)invoiceDescription.SelectToken(QBConfig.InvoiceDescription));
```

can be used to convert string to string in c#. This type of code can be used to convert string to int also in c#. But how this type of code can be used to convert string to enum?

Comment: Why are you using `Convert.ToString` with `String` arguments?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a string to an enum in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

You don't use Convert.ToString to strings to other things, you use Convert.ToXxx

If `invoiceDescription.SelectToken(QBConfig.InvoiceDescription)` is returning you a string (or an object that is actually a string, as your cast might indicate) of the enum member name or value, and you want it converting to a particular enum, you should `Enum.Parse<T>` it, like `var e = Enum.Parse<InvoiceToken>((string)invoiceDescription.SelectToken(QBConfig.InvoiceDescription))`, of course replacing InvoiceToken with the actual name of your enum

If `invoiceDescription.SelectToken(QBConfig.InvoiceDescription)` is returning you an int that is the enum member value (not the name) you can also alternatively `Convert.ToInt32()` it and then cast it to the enum type; any int can be cast to an enum

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.parse?view=net-5.0#System_Enum_Parse__1_System_String_) for enum parse

(It's probably also worth noting that `Enum.Parse<T>` is more recent than other forms; if youre on an older version of .NET you're looking at something more like `(T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), string_here)`)

Comment: To add to the string to int part, [there are more options, like Parse and TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number)

Comment: Ineed, though I wasn't aiming to make this answer an exhaustive list of how to convert a string to an int, because the focus is on enums