# How to update Enum value in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to update Enum value which display Status with three value, `Open, OnHold, Close`

```cs
public enum TicketStatus
{
    Otvoren = 1,
    NaCekanju = 2,
    Zatvoren = 3
}
```

I assign this value to my Model field and give the default value of `Open`

```cs
public string Status { get; set; } = TicketStatus.Otvoren.ToString();
```

Right now the problem start when I want to update this value, and change from `Open` to `OnHold` or `Close`

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Upsert(TicketVM ticketVM)
{
    var users = _unitOfwork.ApplicationUser.GetAll(x => x.Id == x.UserName);
    var userName = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
    var user = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (ticketVM.Ticket.Id == 0)
        {
            ticketVM.Ticket.ApplicationUser = _db.ApplicationUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == userName);
            ticketVM.Ticket.Status = TicketStatus.Otvoren.ToString();
            _unitOfwork.Ticket.Add(ticketVM.Ticket);
        }
        else
        {
            ticketVM.Ticket.ApplicationUser = _db.ApplicationUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == userName);
            
            _unitOfwork.Ticket.Update(ticketVM.Ticket);
        }
        _unitOfwork.Save();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(ticketVM);
}
```

Here is the Upsert method where Status should be updated. So far what I try is this:

**Method 1**

```cs
if (ticketVM.Ticket.Status == "Otvoren")
{
    ticketVM.Ticket.Status = TicketStatus.NaCekanju.ToString();
    ticketVM.Ticket.Status = TicketStatus.Zatvoren.ToString();
}
else if (ticketVM.Ticket.Status == "NaCekanju")
{
    ticketVM.Ticket.Status = TicketStatus.Otvoren.ToString();
    ticketVM.Ticket.Status = TicketStatus.Zatvoren.ToString();
}
else if(ticketVM.Ticket.Status == "Zatvoren")
{
    ticketVM.Ticket.Status = TicketStatus.Otvoren.ToString();
    ticketVM.Ticket.Status = TicketStatus.NaCekanju.ToString();
}
```

**Method 2**

```cs
if (status == "Otvoren")
{
    status = TicketStatus.Otvoren.ToString();
}
else if (status == "NaCekanju")
{
    status = TicketStatus.NaCekanju.ToString();
}
else if (status == "Zatvoren")
{
    status = TicketStatus.Zatvoren.ToString();
}
```

**Method 3**

```cs
switch (status)
{
    case "Otvoren":
        TicketStatus.Otvoren.ToString();
        break;
    case "NaCekanju":
        TicketStatus.NaCekanju.ToString();
        break;
    case "Zatvoren":
        TicketStatus.Zatvoren.ToString();
        break;
}
```

And here is my HTML dropdown

```html
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <label>Status Tiketa</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
        <select asp-for="@Model.Ticket" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<VmSTicketing.Models.Enum.TicketStatus>()" class="form-control"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

- Method 1 doesn't update status at all, and value is always default as it is `Open`
- Method 2 same as Method 1
- Method 3 doesn't work at all too

My question is: How can I update value from `enum` dropdown menu using ?

Comment: Note, I would keep `Status` a `TicketStatus` type,  and only convert it ToString when I pass it to a string output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a string to an enum in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @JHBonarius Can you write this in my example please ?

Comment: Maybe the dupe is wrong. The question is not clear. When do you want to update? What's the trigger? What is `status` (without the capital S). And do I understand that your TicketVM contains the whole Ticket Entity? Kind of defies the idea of a view model...

Comment: Since you're already using the htmlhelper https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-dropdownlist-dropdownlistfor

Comment: @JHBonarius Yes, TicketVM containt Status. I want to update status and all other parameter in my TIcketVM entry

Comment: If you check my `Upsert` method you will see in `else` you can find something like 
`tickeVM.Ticket.Update()` and before this method I would like to update status as well.

Comment: But status has three value, and all three value I need to be updated. If user submit ticket it is by defaul `Open`, and As Admin User I want to change to OnHold or Close depending of what I want

Comment: According to your code there is a `status` and a `Status`. Those are different objects. It is not clear what does what and when you mean which. Be specific please.

Comment: Avoid status, only Status is correct. This `status` doesn't exist in my code anymore

Comment: "depending of what I want" it is impossible for the computer to know what you want. You have to tell it what to do. From your code it is not clear what should happen in what case. Maybe you should clarify that first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229927/discussion-between-unknowuser-and-jhbonarius).

Comment: @JHBonarius By default status is assign as `Open`. And As Admin I want to update this status to `OnHold` or `Close`. `ticketVM.Ticket.Status` is only important in this time. Avoid `status` object, I deleted from my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML is not sending any value for ticket status, and the model binder is always using the default initialized value.

Change the `asp-for` in `select` tag from `@Model.Ticket` to `@Model.Ticket.Status` -

```html
<select asp-for="@Model.Ticket.Status" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<VmSTicketing.Models.Enum.TicketStatus>()" class="form-control"></select>
```

This will give you the string representation of the `int` value you set to the enum members. You can get the enum string from that and set it to the ticket status, like -

```cs
ticketVM.Ticket.Status = ((TicketStatus)Convert.ToInt32(ticketVM.Ticket.Status)).ToString();
```

**An alternative approach:**

For create and edit operation, in your controller you have `GET` methods that returns the view. Create a `SelectList` with your enum member names and add it to the `ViewBag` -

```cs
public IActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.StatusList = new SelectList(Enum.GetNames(typeof(TicketStatus)));
    return View();
}
```

and in your HTML change the `select` tag as -

```html
<select asp-for="@Model.Ticket.Status" asp-items="ViewBag.StatusList" class="form-control"></select>
```

Now you will get the enum member name selected in the dropdown as the value for `ticketVM.Ticket.Status` in the controller and you don't have to do anything to set this value.

Comment: Thank you. But once I change status and when I again call method it is not display changed status. For example if I change status to `OnHold` and save action, it redirect to index page, and when I again call edit method it display previous status `Open`

Comment: @UnKnowUser Is the Status value is updating successfully?

Comment: Yes it is updated successfully, but it doesn't save previous status.

Comment: @UnKnowUser Did it work correctly before you fix the current issue? From the answer which approach for `asp-items` did you apply - your previous existing approach or the `ViewBag.StatusList` approach?

Comment: I implement first approach not second.

Comment: @UnKnowUser Did it work correctly before you fix the current issue?

Comment: No, It didn't work correctly. Even before didn't works at all

Comment: @UnKnowUser Then it can depend on a lot of things. I would suggest you post another question clearly describing issue. Specifically with the code for the index page and how you are loading data for that page.

Comment: Thank you for answer however ! I will try to find the figure out this error ! :)