# (C#) how to get Key from string

Tags: c#, .net, windows, forms

When I say Key, I'm referring to the "Keys" enum in Windows Forms. For instance:

I might have a string:

```
string key = "Q";
```

And I'm trying to convert it to this:

```
Keys.Q
```

How would I do this? (If even possible)

Comment: Use `Enum.TryParse("Q", out Keys key);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a string to an enum in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

In case that the values of the string are not exactly the same as the enum you can do it with a switch-case statment.

```
Keys keys = key switch
{
    "Q" => Keys.Q
    ...
};
```

If the values exactly the same just parse it:

```
public static TEnum ToEnum<TEnum>(this string strEnumValue)
{
    if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(TEnum), strEnumValue))
    {
        throw new Exception("Enum can't be parsed");
    }

    return (TEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(TEnum), strEnumValue);
}

Keys keys = key.ToEnum<Keys>();
```