# How do I determine if an Enum value has one or more of the values it's being compared with?

Tags: c#, enums, flags

I've got an Enum marked with the [Flags] attribute as follows:

```
[Flags]
public enum Tag : int
{
    None = 0,
    PrimaryNav = 1,
    HideChildPages = 2,
    HomePage = 4,
    FooterLink = 8
}
```

On sitemapnodes in my sitemap I store the int value for the tags combination as an attribute.

What I need to do is check if a node has ***any one*** of one or more tags, e.g. Tag.PrimaryNav | Tag.HomePage.

I'm struggling with the necessary boolean logic to determine if an Enum value has one or more of the values it's being compared with.

Apologies if this isn't clear.  I can provide more information if necessary.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69483892/543814). It handles only checking for "any one of **all defined flags**", but you may be able to adapt it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can do that by combining values with `|` and checking via `&`.

To check if the value contains *either* of the tags:

```
if ((myValue & (Tag.PrimaryNav | Tag.HomePage)) != 0) { ... }
```

The `|` combines the enums you're testing (bitwise) and the `&` tests via bitwise masking -- if the result isn't zero, it has at least one of them set.

If you want to test whether it has *both* of them set, you can do that as well:

```
Tag desiredValue = Tag.PrimaryNav | Tag.HomePage;
if ((myValue & desiredValue) == desiredValue) { ... }
```

Here we're masking off anything we don't care about, and testing that the resulting value equals what we *do* care about (we can't use `!= 0` like before because that would match *either* value and here we're interested in *both*).

Some links:

- [The `&` Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx)
- [The `|` Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx(v=VS.90).aspx)

Answer (score 9):

You can use the HasFlag Method to avoid the need for the boolean logic,

```
Tag Val = (Tag)9;

if (Val.HasFlag(Tag.PrimaryNav))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Primary Nav");
}

if(Val.HasFlag(Tag.HomePage))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Home Page");
}
```

Comment: This method is new in .NET 4.0, so it won't work if the OP is using an earlier version...

Comment: yea then use any of the other methods list just wanted to throw it out there.

Answer (score 2):

For bitwise (`Flags`) enums, an "any of" test is != 0, so:

```
const Tag flagsToLookFor = Tag.PrimaryNav | Tag.HomePage;
if ((node.Tag & flagsToLookFor) != 0) {
    // has some cross-over with PrimaryNav or HomePage (and possibly others too) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var someEnumValue = Tag.PrimaryNav | Tag.HomePage;
```

To test if the enum contains a given value:

```
if ((someEnumValue & Tag.PrimaryNav) == Tag.PrimaryNav)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var tag = Tag.HideChildPages | Tag.PrimaryNav;

If ((tag & Tag.PrimaryNav) == Tag.PrimaryNav) {
    // Tag.PrimaryNav set.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Jon Skeet's [Unconstrained Melody](http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/) library:

```
var someEnumValue = Tag.PrimaryNav | Tag.HideChildPages;
someEnumValue.HasAny(Tag.PrimaryNav | Tag.HomePage); // Returns true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension method on enum, for any type of enums:

```
public static bool IsSingle(this Enum value)
    {
        var items = Enum.GetValues(value.GetType());
        var counter = 0;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (value.HasFlag((Enum)item))
            {
                counter++;
            }
            if (counter > 1)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a classic Extension method:

```
    public static bool HasFlag(this Enum val, Enum t)
    {
            return (Convert.ToUInt64(val) & Convert.ToUInt64(t)) != 0;
    }
```

Comment: Obviously locate it in a public static class, located in a namespace you've added to the "using" in your class