# How to iterate over values of an Enum having flags?

Tags: c#, enums, enum-flags

If I have a variable holding a flags enum, can I somehow iterate over the single-bit values in that specific variable? Or do I have to use `Enum.GetValues` to iterate over the entire enum and check which ones are set?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Coming back at this a few years later, with a bit more experience, my ultimate answer for single-bit values only, moving from lowest bit to highest bit, is a slight variant of Jeff Mercado's inner routine:

```
public static IEnumerable<Enum> GetUniqueFlags(this Enum flags)
{
    ulong flag = 1;
    foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(flags.GetType()).Cast<Enum>())
    {
        ulong bits = Convert.ToUInt64(value);
        while (flag < bits)
        {
            flag <<= 1;
        }

        if (flag == bits && flags.HasFlag(value))
        {
            yield return value;
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to work, and despite my objections of some years ago, I use HasFlag here, since it's far more legible than using bitwise comparisons and the speed difference is insignificant for anything I'll be doing. (It's entirely possible they've improved the speed of HasFlags since then anyway, for all I know...I haven't tested.)

Comment: This is the only solution I found that seems to also not suffer from the fact that if you have a flag with value zero, which should represent "None", other  answers GetFlag() methods will return the YourEnum.None as one of the flags even if it isn't actually in the enum you are running the method on! I was getting weird duplicate log entries because methods were running more times than I expected when they had only one non-zero enum flag set. Thanks for taking the time to update and add in this great solution!

Comment: This is a decent solution, but has one quirk - if you use signed int64 value, it'll not find the most significant bit.

Answer (score 214):

```
static IEnumerable<Enum> GetFlags(Enum input)
{
    foreach (Enum value in Enum.GetValues(input.GetType()))
        if (input.HasFlag(value))
            yield return value;
}
```

Comment: Note that `HasFlag` is available from .NET 4 onwards.

Comment: This is great! But You can make it even simpler and easy to use. Just stick this as an extension method:

`Enum.GetValues(input.GetType()).Cast<Enum>().Where(input.HasFlag);`

Then just: `myEnum.GetFLags()` :)

Comment: Great one-liner, josh, but it still suffers the problem of picking up multi-flag values (Boo) instead of only single-flag values (Bar, Baz), as in Jeff's answer, above.

Comment: Nice - watch out for None's though - e.g. Items.None from Jeff's answer will always be included

Comment: Method signature should be `static IEnumerable<Enum> GetFlags(this Enum input)`

Comment: Exclude the Items.None flag by creating the flag with value 0 (`var zeroFlag = Enum.Parse(input.GetType(), "0");`) and adding `!zeroFlag.Equals(value)` to the `HasFlag` check

Comment: `if (Convert.ToInt32(value) != 0 && input.HasFlag(value))`

Answer (score 73):

Here is a Linq solution to the problem.

```
public static IEnumerable<Enum> GetFlags(this Enum e)
{
      return Enum.GetValues(e.GetType()).Cast<Enum>().Where(e.HasFlag);
}
```

Comment: Why isn't this at the top?? :) Use `.Where(v => !Equals((int)(object)v, 0) && e.HasFlag(v));` if you have a zero value to represent `None`

Comment: @georgiosd I guess the performance is not that great. (But should be good enough for most tasks)

Comment: @georgiosd: This fails if the underlying type is not `int`. You should use `var zero = (T)Convert.ChangeType (0, Enum.GetUnderlyingType (typeof(T)));` and check `.Where (enumValue => !Equals (enumValue, zero))`

Answer (score 40):

There aren't any builtin methods to get each component as far as I know. But here's one way you can get them:

```
[Flags]
enum Items
{
    None = 0x0,
    Foo  = 0x1,
    Bar  = 0x2,
    Baz  = 0x4,
    Boo  = 0x6,
}

var value = Items.Foo | Items.Bar;
var values = value.ToString()
                  .Split(new[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.None)
                  .Select(v => (Items)Enum.Parse(typeof(Items), v));

// This method will always end up with the most applicable values
value = Items.Bar | Items.Baz;
values = value.ToString()
              .Split(new[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.None)
              .Select(v => (Items)Enum.Parse(typeof(Items), v)); // Boo
```

---

I adapted what `Enum` does internally to generate the string to instead return the flags.  You can look at the code in reflector and should be more or less equivalent.  Works well for general use cases where there are values which contain multiple bits.

```
static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Enum> GetFlags(this Enum value)
    {
        return GetFlags(value, Enum.GetValues(value.GetType()).Cast<Enum>().ToArray());
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Enum> GetIndividualFlags(this Enum value)
    {
        return GetFlags(value, GetFlagValues(value.GetType()).ToArray());
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Enum> GetFlags(Enum value, Enum[] values)
    {
        ulong bits = Convert.ToUInt64(value);
        List<Enum> results = new List<Enum>();
        for (int i = values.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            ulong mask = Convert.ToUInt64(values[i]);
            if (i == 0 && mask == 0L)
                break;
            if ((bits & mask) == mask)
            {
                results.Add(values[i]);
                bits -= mask;
            }
        }
        if (bits != 0L)
            return Enumerable.Empty<Enum>();
        if (Convert.ToUInt64(value) != 0L)
            return results.Reverse<Enum>();
        if (bits == Convert.ToUInt64(value) && values.Length > 0 && Convert.ToUInt64(values[0]) == 0L)
            return values.Take(1);
        return Enumerable.Empty<Enum>();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Enum> GetFlagValues(Type enumType)
    {
        ulong flag = 0x1;
        foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(enumType).Cast<Enum>())
        {
            ulong bits = Convert.ToUInt64(value);
            if (bits == 0L)
                //yield return value;
                continue; // skip the zero value
            while (flag < bits) flag <<= 1;
            if (flag == bits)
                yield return value;
        }
    }
}
```

The extension method `GetIndividualFlags()` gets all the individual flags for a type.  So values containing multiple bits are left out.

```
var value = Items.Bar | Items.Baz;
value.GetFlags();           // Boo
value.GetIndividualFlags(); // Bar, Baz
```

Comment: Unfortunately by doing so, you'd have to test for redundant values (if to did not want them).  See my second example, it would yield `Bar`, `Baz` and `Boo` instead of just `Boo`.

Comment: @Robin: You're right, the original would return `Boo` (the value returned using `ToString()`).  I've tweaked it to allow only individual flags.  So in my example, you can get `Bar` and `Baz` instead of `Boo`.

Comment: Note that if your enum has negative values (for example with Visual Studio extensibility framework, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop._VSRDTFLAGS) then the use of ulong and ToUInt64 here will cause problems.  If you replace with long and ToInt64 then it'll handle enums with negative values.

Comment: Since .NET 6 `BitOperations.IsPow2()` may simplify `GetFlagValues` to a one-liner.

Answer (score 26):

Going off of @Greg's method, but adding a new feature from C# 7.3, the `Enum` constraint:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetUniqueFlags<T>(this T flags)
    where T : Enum    // New constraint for C# 7.3
{
    foreach (Enum value in Enum.GetValues(flags.GetType()))
        if (flags.HasFlag(value))
            yield return (T)value;
}
```

The new constraint allows this to be an extension method, without having to cast through `(int)(object)e`, and I can use the `HasFlag` method and cast directly to `T` from `value`.

C# 7.3 also added constraints for delegates and `unmanaged`.

Answer (score 16):

+1 for the answer provided by @RobinHood70. I found that a generic version of the method was convenient for me.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetUniqueFlags<T>(this Enum flags)
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
        throw new ArgumentException("The generic type parameter must be an Enum.");

    if (flags.GetType() != typeof(T))
        throw new ArgumentException("The generic type parameter does not match the target type.");

    ulong flag = 1;
    foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(flags.GetType()).Cast<T>())
    {
        ulong bits = Convert.ToUInt64(value);
        while (flag < bits)
        {
            flag <<= 1;
        }

        if (flag == bits && flags.HasFlag(value as Enum))
        {
            yield return value;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
And +1 for @AustinWBryan for bringing C# 7.3 into the solution space.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetUniqueFlags<T>(this T flags) where T : Enum
{
    ulong flag = 1;
    foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(flags.GetType()).Cast<T>())
    {
        ulong bits = Convert.ToUInt64(value);
        while (flag < bits)
        {
            flag <<= 1;
        }

        if (flag == bits && flags.HasFlag(value as Enum))
        {
            yield return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Extension method using the new Enum constraint and generics to prevent casting:

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static T[] GetFlags<T>(this T flagsEnumValue) where T : Enum
    {
        return Enum
            .GetValues(typeof(T))
            .Cast<T>()
            .Where(e => flagsEnumValue.HasFlag(e))
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's yet another C# 7.3 solution using Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class FlagEnumExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetFlags<T>(this T en) where T : struct, Enum
    {
        return Enum.GetValues<T>().Where(member => en.HasFlag(member)).ToArray();
    }
}
```

**Edit:** added `.ToArray()` to prevent multiple enumerations.

Answer (score 5):

Continuing in my efforts to make the code shorter, this is my latest version of the routine. (I'm the OP...long story.) As discussed previously, this ignores None and multi-bit values.

Note that this uses an Enum constraint and a var pattern, so will require at least C# 7.3.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetUniqueFlags<T>(this T value)
    where T : Enum
{
    var valueLong = Convert.ToUInt64(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    foreach (var enumValue in value.GetType().GetEnumValues())
    {
        if (
            enumValue is T flag // cast enumValue to T
            && Convert.ToUInt64(flag, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) is var bitValue // convert flag to ulong
            && (bitValue & (bitValue - 1)) == 0 // is this a single-bit value?
            && (valueLong & bitValue) != 0 // is the bit set?
           )
        {
            yield return flag;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For a significant performance boost, you can cast the result of `GetEnumValues()` to `T[]` and eliminate the `enumValue is T flag` condition, but this relies on GetEnumValues always returning an array of type T, which it's not contractually required to do.

Comment: Why not simply use `Enum.GetValues<T>()`? It's been around for a while now

Comment: Unless it's changed, Enum.GetValues<T>() returns all values in an enum, not the unique ones, so if you have combination values for convenience (e.g., ALL = READ | WRITE | EXECUTE | DELETE), it'll return that, which is not what's wanted. We only want the single-bit flags. It was also only introduced in C# 8, whereas this applies to 7.3. (And earlier responses apply to even earlier C#'s.)

Comment: Yes, however, your code as it is written, requires you to cast the enum values inside the loop. I just tested it in a .NET fiddle; using `Enum.GetValues<T>()` instead of `value.GetType().GetEnumValues()` in your foreach produces type-safe enum values, so no `enumValue is T flag` cast is needed.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good tip for C# 8+, but as I said above, this post was written with 7.3 in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Wasn't satisfied with the answers above, although they were the start.

After piecing together some different sources here:
[Previous poster in this thread's SO QnA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717550/hasflag-not-recognizing-role-assignment)
[Code Project Enum Flags Check Post](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/194233/See-if-a-Flags-enum-is-valid?display=Print)
[Great Enum<T> Utility](http://devlicious.com/blogs/christopher_bennage/archive/2007/09/13/my-new-little-friend-enum-lt-t-gt.aspx)

I created this so let me know what you think.
Parameters:
`bool checkZero`: tells it to allow `0` as a flag value. By default `input = 0` returns empty.
`bool checkFlags`: tells it to check whether the `Enum` is decorated w/ the `[Flags]` attribute.
PS. I don't have time right now to figure out the `checkCombinators = false` alg which will force it to ignore any enum values which are combinations of bits.

```
    public static IEnumerable<TEnum> GetFlags<TEnum>(this TEnum input, bool checkZero = false, bool checkFlags = true, bool checkCombinators = true)
    {
        Type enumType = typeof(TEnum);
        if (!enumType.IsEnum)
            yield break;

        ulong setBits = Convert.ToUInt64(input);
        // if no flags are set, return empty
        if (!checkZero && (0 == setBits))
            yield break;

        // if it's not a flag enum, return empty
        if (checkFlags && !input.GetType().IsDefined(typeof(FlagsAttribute), false))
            yield break;

        if (checkCombinators)
        {
            // check each enum value mask if it is in input bits
            foreach (TEnum value in Enum<TEnum>.GetValues())
            {
                ulong valMask = Convert.ToUInt64(value);

                if ((setBits & valMask) == valMask)
                    yield return value;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // check each enum value mask if it is in input bits
            foreach (TEnum value in Enum <TEnum>.GetValues())
            {
                ulong valMask = Convert.ToUInt64(value);

                if ((setBits & valMask) == valMask)
                    yield return value;
            }
        }

    }
```

This makes use of the Helper Class [Enum<T> found here](http://devlicious.com/blogs/christopher_bennage/archive/2007/09/13/my-new-little-friend-enum-lt-t-gt.aspx) that I updated to use `yield return` for `GetValues`:

```
public static class Enum<TEnum>
{
    public static TEnum Parse(string value)
    {
        return (TEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(TEnum), value);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TEnum> GetValues()   
    {
        foreach (object value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)))
            yield return ((TEnum)value);
    }
}
```

Finally, here's a example of using it:

```
    private List<CountType> GetCountTypes(CountType countTypes)
    {
        List<CountType> cts = new List<CountType>();

        foreach (var ct in countTypes.GetFlags())
            cts.Add(ct);

        return cts;
    }
```

Comment: Just a heads up that there's a bug in that code. The code in both branches of the if(checkCombinators) statement are identical. Also, perhaps not a bug, but unexpected, is that if you have an enum value declared for 0, it will always be returned in the collection. It seems that should only be returned if checkZero is true and there are no other flags set.

Comment: @dhochee. I agree. Or the code is pretty nice, but arguments are confusing.

Answer (score 3):

What I did was change my approach, instead of typing the input parameter of the method as the `enum` type, I typed it as an array of the `enum` type (`MyEnum[] myEnums`),  this way I just iterate through the array with a switch statement inside the loop.

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to performance, which is important in game development, all solutions given are terrible because of garbage allocation and slow speed. This is a garbage free, over 100 times faster solution than accepted answer.

```
[Flags]
public enum PersonalTraits : short
{
    None = 1 << 0,
    Strength = 1 << 1,
    Agility = 1 << 2,
    Attack = 1 << 3,
    Defence = 1 << 4,
    Vitality = 1 << 5,
    Stamina = 1 << 6,
    Accuracy = 1 << 7,
    Perception = 1 << 8,
    Charisma = 1 << 9,
}
PersonalTraits athlete = PersonalTraits.Stamina | PersonalTraits.Strength;

for (short i = 0, value = 0; value <= (short)PersonalTraits.Charisma; i++, value = (short)(1 << i))
    if (((short)athlete & value) != 0)
       yield return (PersonalTraits)value;
```

Comment: Your solution only works for one specific enum.

Answer (score 3):

In .NET 6

```
Enum.GetValues<yourenum>().Where(e => input.HasFlag(e));
```

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to iterate all values. just check your specific flags like so:

```
if((myVar & FlagsEnum.Flag1) == FlagsEnum.Flag1) 
{
   //do something...
}
```

or (as [pstrjds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/416574/pstrjds) said in comments) you can check for use it like:

```
if(myVar.HasFlag(FlagsEnum.Flag1))
{
   //do something...
}
```

Comment: If you are using .Net 4.0 there is an extension method HasFlag that you can use to do the same thing: myVar.HasFlag(FlagsEnum.Flag1)

Answer (score 2):

Building upon Greg's answer above, this also takes care of the case where you have a value 0 in your enum, such as None = 0. In which case, it should not iterate over that value.

```
public static IEnumerable<Enum> ToEnumerable(this Enum input)
{
    foreach (Enum value in Enum.GetValues(input.GetType()))
        if (input.HasFlag(value) && Convert.ToInt64(value) != 0)
            yield return value;
}
```

Would anyone know how to improve upon this even further so that it can handle the case where all flags in the enum are set in a super smart way that could handle all underlying enum type and the case of All = ~0 and All = EnumValue1 | EnumValue2 | EnumValue3 | ...

Answer (score 2):

All the answers work well with simple flags, you're probably going to get into issues when flags are combined.

```
[Flags]
enum Food
{
  None=0
  Bread=1,
  Pasta=2,
  Apples=4,
  Banana=8,
  WithGluten=Bread|Pasta,
  Fruits = Apples | Banana,
}
```

probably need to add a check to test if the enum value it self is a combination. 
You'd probably need something like posted here by [Henk van Boeijen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339976/how-to-check-if-any-flags-of-a-flag-combination-are-set) 
to cover your requirement (you need to scroll down a bit)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Iterator from the Enum. Starting from the MSDN code:

```
public class DaysOfTheWeek : System.Collections.IEnumerable
{
    int[] dayflag = { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64 };
    string[] days = { "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun" };
    public string value { get; set; }

    public System.Collections.IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < days.Length; i++)
        {
            if value >> i & 1 == dayflag[i] {
                yield return days[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's not tested, so if I made a mistake feel free to call me out. (obviously it's not re-entrant.) You'd have to assign value beforehand, or break it out into another function that uses enum.dayflag and enum.days. You might be able to go somewhere with the outline.

Answer (score 0):

It could be aswell as the following code:

```
public static string GetEnumString(MyEnum inEnumValue)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (MyEnum e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum )))
    {
        if ((e & inEnumValue) != 0)
        {
           sb.Append(e.ToString());
           sb.Append(", ");
        }
    }

   return sb.ToString().Trim().TrimEnd(',');
}
```

It goes inside if only when the enum value is contained on the value

Answer (score -2):

You can do it directly by converting to int but you will loose type checking. 
I think the best way is use something similar to my proposition. It keep the proper type all the way. No conversion required. It is not perfect due to boxing which will add a little hit in performance.

Not perfect (boxing), but it does the job with no warning...

```
/// <summary>
/// Return an enumerators of input flag(s)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="input"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static IEnumerable<T> GetFlags<T>(this T input)
{
    foreach (Enum value in Enum.GetValues(input.GetType()))
    {
        if ((int) (object) value != 0) // Just in case somebody has defined an enum with 0.
        {
            if (((Enum) (object) input).HasFlag(value))
                yield return (T) (object) value;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    FileAttributes att = FileAttributes.Normal | FileAttributes.Compressed;
    foreach (FileAttributes fa in att.GetFlags())
    {
        ...
    }
```