# HasFlag not recognizing role assignment

Tags: c#, .net, authorization, bit-manipulation

I'm using an Enum decorated with [Flags] to control autoization within my MVC2 app.  Below is my code examples:

```
[Flags]
public enum SecurityRoles
{
    None = 0,
    Executive = 1,
    BackOffice = 2,
    AccountManager = 4,
    Consultant = 8,
    Administrator = 16
}

[TestMethod]
public void MultipleSelectionsTest()
{
    var requiredRoles = SecurityRoles.Executive | SecurityRoles.BackOffice;
    var user1Roles = SecurityRoles.Executive | SecurityRoles.Administrator | SecurityRoles.BackOffice | SecurityRoles.Consultant;
    var user1HasAccess = user1Roles.HasFlag(requiredRoles);

    var user2Roles = SecurityRoles.Administrator | SecurityRoles.BackOffice | SecurityRoles.Consultant;
    var user2HasAccess = user2Roles.HasFlag(requiredRoles);


    Assert.IsTrue(user1HasAccess);  //returns true
    Assert.IsTrue(user2HasAccess);  //returns false
}
```

As you can see, user2Roles containes BackOffice role and requiredRoles also contains BackOffice role, however, user2HasAccess is false.  Why is that?  What am I missing?  user1HasAccess is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong (because I could be), but when you perform Enum flag checks, .NET is essentially doing binary arithmetic on an integer which represents the sum of the flags.

So having `SecurityRoles.Administrator | SecurityRoles.BackOffice | SecurityRoles.Consultant` is the same as having a value of 26 or `11010` in binary.

When you make the call to Enum.HasFlags, the operation that's being performed is `return thisInstance & flag == flag`

So if you're checking the previously mentioned flag set against your required roles of `SecurityRoles.Executive | SecurityRoles.BackOffice` a value of 3 or `11` in binary, the math goes something like this:

```
11010 - 26 Administrator | BackOffice | Consultant
00011 -  3 Executive | BackOffice
----- 
00010 -  2 BackOffice which really doesn't mean anything useful
```

Then it would follow that `26 & 3 == 3` is false.

And for the sake of being thorough, given `SecurityRoles.Executive | SecurityRoles.Administrator | SecurityRoles.BackOffice | SecurityRoles.Consultant` a value of 27 or `11011` in binary, the math goes like this:

```
11011 - 26 Executive  | Administrator | BackOffice | Consultant
00011 -  3 Executive | BackOffice
----- 
00011 -  3 Executive | BackOffice
```

Then it would follow that `26 & 3 == 3` is true.

An extension method something like this, might be worthwhile (untested)

```
public static bool HasFlags(this Enum source, Enum[] flags) 
{
    return flags.Any(f => source.HasFlag(f));
}
```

Comment: Your extensionmethod can be improved, this solution is probably faster: public static bool HasAnyFlag(this Enum source, Enum flags) { return (source & flags) != 0; }. Also untested btw

Comment: @Tomas. Sry, it should obviously have been `public static bool HasAnyFlag(this Enum source, Enum flags) { return (Convert.ToInt32(source) & Convert.ToInt32(flags)) != 0; }`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help Wes P.  I was able to take your suggestion and combine it with the extension found here: [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171140/iterate-over-values-in-flags-enum) and came up with my own extension to solve the problem

Here's me extension.  It uses the GetFlags() method found in the extension methods i found in the link above.

```
public static bool HasFlags(this Enum userRoles, Enum requiredRoles)
        {
            var hasFlags = false;
            var userRolesList = userRoles.GetFlags();
            var requiredRolesList = requiredRoles.GetFlags();

            foreach (var role in userRolesList)
            {
                var role1 = role;
                hasFlags = requiredRolesList.Any(securityRole => role1.CompareTo(securityRole) == 0);

                if(hasFlags)
                    break;
            }

            return hasFlags;
        }
```