# Printing Flags Enum as Separate Flags

Tags: c#, enums, flags

I have a flags enum defined like this:

```
[Flags]
public enum MyEnum
{
    None =     0x00,
    Choice1 =  0x01,
    Choice2 =  0x02,
    Choice3 =  0x04,
    Default =  Choice1 | Choice2,
    All =      Default | Choice3
}
```

I would like a way to print out which flags are included in `MyEnum.Default`.  In this case, I'd want the output to be something like "Choice1, Choice2".

The problem with simply printing `MyEnum.Default.ToString()` is that the output would be "Default" when I want "Choice1, Choice2".

Here's one option, but if I used this I'd have to update the printing every time I changed the enum.

```
((StudyData.Choice1 & StudyData.Default) == StudyData.Choice1 ? StudyData.Choice1.ToString() : "") + ", " +
((StudyData.Choice2 & StudyData.Default) == StudyData.Choice2 ? StudyData.Choice2.ToString() : "") + ", " +
((StudyData.Choice3 & StudyData.Default) == StudyData.Choice3 ? StudyData.Choice3.ToString() : "")
```

Does anyone have a cleaner way of doing this?  Ideally, I'd like a way of printing out the flags included in `MyEnum.Default` without having to change the printing code every time I added a new flag or changed the default.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using the extension methods I've written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171140/iterate-over-values-in-flags-enum/4171168#4171168) on a related question, this should be simple:

```
var value = MyEnum.Default;
var str = String.Join(", ", value.GetIndividualFlags());
// "Choice1, Choice2"
```

And here's the extension methods:

```
static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Enum> GetFlags(this Enum value)
    {
        return GetFlags(value, Enum.GetValues(value.GetType()).Cast<Enum>().ToArray());
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Enum> GetIndividualFlags(this Enum value)
    {
        return GetFlags(value, GetFlagValues(value.GetType()).ToArray());
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Enum> GetFlags(Enum value, Enum[] values)
    {
        ulong bits = Convert.ToUInt64(value);
        List<Enum> results = new List<Enum>();
        for (int i = values.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            ulong mask = Convert.ToUInt64(values[i]);
            if (i == 0 && mask == 0L)
                break;
            if ((bits & mask) == mask)
            {
                results.Add(values[i]);
                bits -= mask;
            }
        }
        if (bits != 0L)
            return Enumerable.Empty<Enum>();
        if (Convert.ToUInt64(value) != 0L)
            return results.Reverse<Enum>();
        if (bits == Convert.ToUInt64(value) && values.Length > 0 && Convert.ToUInt64(values[0]) == 0L)
            return values.Take(1);
        return Enumerable.Empty<Enum>();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Enum> GetFlagValues(Type enumType)
    {
        ulong flag = 0x1;
        foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(enumType).Cast<Enum>())
        {
            ulong bits = Convert.ToUInt64(value);
            if (bits == 0L)
                //yield return value;
                continue; // skip the zero value
            while (flag < bits) flag <<= 1;
            if (flag == bits)
                yield return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that if your enum has negative values (for example with Visual Studio extensibility framework, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop._VSRDTFLAGS) then the use of ulong and ToUInt64 here will cause problems.  If you replace with long and ToInt64 then it'll handle enums with negative values.

Answer (score 11):

Decorate your enum with [FlagsAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=netframework-4.8).  It does pretty much exactly what you're after:

```
[Flags]
public enum FooNum
{
    foo = 0,
    bar = 1,
    lulz = 2,
    borkbork = 4
}

FooNum f = FooNum.bar | FooNum.borkbork;

Debug.WriteLine(f.ToString());
```

should give you:

bar, borkbork

Comment: Oops!  I forgot to include the FlagsAttribute in my copy-paste.  I'm going to fix the original question.  Thanks for the fast response and sorry for the confusion...

Comment: Ohhhh... I see what you're doing now.  The problem with this one is even if you manually construct the `Default` with `yourEnum = yourEnum.Choice1 | yourEnum.Choice2` you will STILL get `yourEnum.Default` when you push it out to a string.   How badly do you need the Default and All definitions on the enum itself?  You're going to have to walk the bits and pull them separately like you've already found out.  It's going to be a little messy no matter what.  A different option would be to store your defaults as their own FooNum.  That's messy in its own way though...

Comment: The gotcha that might be getting some people looking at this is that you need to set a value for each of your enum values that are unique and is a power of 2, like 1, 2, 4, 8, etc. If you don't set a value, the implicit values will be 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. So when you pipe them together (binary OR), it will not give the expected value.

Answer (score 3):

Use `flags.ToString("g");`
See [Enumeration Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/enumeration-format-strings)

Comment: Thanks!  So much simpler than all other answers.

Answer (score 2):

Print by single linq statement:

```
var names = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))
    .Cast<MyEnum>()
    .Where(a => (values & a) == a)
    .Select(a => a.ToString())
    .Aggregate((current, next) => current + ", " + next);
```

**Updated version to print only explicitly defined values:**

```
var values = MyEnum.All;

var allAttrs = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<MyEnum>();

var names = allAttrs
    // leave only explicitly defined and not zero values
    .Where(attr => allAttrs.Count(a => a != 0 && (attr & a) == a) == 1)   
    .Where(a => (values & a) == a)
    .Select(a=>a.ToString())
    .Aggregate((current, next) => current + ", " + next);

Console.WriteLine(names); // Choice1, Choice2, Choice3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Text;

namespace printStar
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            Console.WriteLine("Enter the value ");
            int k = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int n = k - 1;
            int x = 2 * (k - 1) + 1;

            for (int p = 0; p <= n; p++)
            {
                for (int j = k - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }

                for (int i = 0; i <= (x - 2 * (k - 1)); i++)
                {
                    if (i % 2 == 1)
                    {
                        Console.Write("*");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write(" ");
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
                k--;
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this in the shortest, clearest code possible that I expect performs well, although there is boxing in a couple of places. Using your type as an example:

```
MyEnum e = MyEnum.Choice1 | MyEnum.Choice2;
string s = FlagsEnumToString<MyEnum>(e); // Returns "Choice1, Choice2"
```

This is how it's implemented:

```
const string Separator = ", ";

public static string FlagsEnumToString<T>(Enum e)
{
    var str = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (object i in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
    {
        if (IsExactlyOneBitSet((int) i) &&
            e.HasFlag((Enum) i))
        {
            str.Append((T) i + Separator);
        }
    }

    if (str.Length > 0)
    {
        str.Length -= Separator.Length;
    }

    return str.ToString();
}

static bool IsExactlyOneBitSet(int i)
{
    return i != 0 && (i & (i - 1)) == 0;
}
```

Some comments might come up and I'll address these first:

> I need to call your method providing both type *and* variable?

Because this can't be done with a generic `T` argument implicitly. `T` can't be cast to `Enum` for use with `HasFlag`. No, also not using `where T : struct, IConvertible`.

> The `foreach` also uses `object`?

Yes, also to be able to cast. Only `object` can be cast to the other types `T`, `int`, `Enum`.

> I think this can be optimized by casting to `int` inside the loop once with a temporary variable.

I think so, yes. This code was written like this for clarity. So yes do that and get rid of those `HasFlag` calls if you like.

> I think you still can use `Enum` as the `foreach` variable and save on casting.

No, because you need a cast to `T` and that can only be done from `object`. There might be 'better' solutions but this is most certainly the shortest and clearest one.