# How to list enum based in combination

Tags: c#

Is possible list a flag based in combination.

Using ProfileTypeFlag.SupplierMaster get a list just of "Supplier | Master | External"

I'm trying use this code. But they return all enums;

```
    public List<string> SetRoles(ProfileTypeFlag role)
        {
            List<string> result = new List<string>();
            foreach (ProfileTypeFlag r in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ProfileTypeFlag)))
            {
                if ((role & r) != 0) result.Add(r.ToString());
            }

          return result;
        }


[Flags]
 public enum ProfileTypeFlag : uint
    {
        None = 0,
        Customer = 1,
        Supplier = 2,
        Internal = 4,
        Delegate = 8,
        Master = 16,
        External = 32,
        CustomerMaster = Customer | Master | External,
        SupplierMaster = Supplier | Master | External
}
```

Comment: Ok... What did you *want* to happen?

Comment: return a list<string> = "Supplier", "Master" , "External" or list<ProfileFlags> with "Supplier", "Master" , "External"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution for you:

```
public static string GetFlagsStringFromUInt32Enum<TEnum>(TEnum value)
    where TEnum : struct
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(var i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
    {
        var bit = (uint)1 << i;
        if (((uint)(object)value & bit) != 0)
            sb.Append((TEnum)(object)bit).Append(" | ");
    }

    if (sb.Length > 0)
        sb.Length -= 3;

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/XjtZts)

This will work on enums based on `uint` like yours, I ddn't bother to implement a general solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just tweak your `if` statement slightly:

```
if ((role & r) == r && r != ProfileTypeFlag.None && role != r)
```

Or you could use `HasFlag` (equivalent to `role & r == r`):

```
if (role.HasFlag(r) && r != ProfileTypeFlag.None && role != r)
```

Basically, if the role includes the flag, it's not the `None` flag, and its not the role itself, then add it to the list.

With that in mind, you could change your whole function to:

```
public List<string> SetRoles(ProfileTypeFlag role)
{    
    return
        Enum.GetValues(typeof(ProfileTypeFlag))
            .Cast<ProfileTypeFlag>()
            .Where(r => r != ProfileTypeFlag.None)
            .Where(r => r != role)
            .Where(r => role.HasFlag(r))
            .Select(r => r.ToString())
            .ToList();
}
```

As @Lucas pointed out, the above solutions don't work quite correctly if your enum value contains compound flags.

One solution to this would be to *remove* flag values as you encounter them:

```
public List<string> SetRoles(ProfileTypeFlag role)
{    
    var result = new List<string>();

    foreach (ProfileTypeFlag r in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ProfileTypeFlag)))
    {
        if (role.HasFlag(r) && r != ProfileTypeFlag.None) 
        {
            result.Add(r.ToString());
            role &= ~r;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I guess it will break on something like `ProfileTypeFlag.SupplierMaster | ProfileTypeFlag.Internal`

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: You're right, your solution might be better

Comment: On the other hand, mine requires all bits to be named, even if they're part of a compound value, or it'll insert the numerical value.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker: actually, I prefer yours for readability. It just needs a little tweak: `return Enum.GetValues(typeof(ProfileTypeFlag)).Cast<ProfileTypeFlag>().Where(r => r != ProfileTypeFlag.None && ((int)r & ((int)r - 1)) == 0 && role.HasFlag(r)).Select(r => r.ToString()).ToList();`  Note that I also prefer all the predicates in a single `Where()` method. It reads just as well, and involves fewer temp objects.

Answer (score 0):

To provide a slightly different approach, you could use this function to get the "set" enums:

```
static IEnumerable<Enum> GetFlags(Enum input)
{
    foreach (Enum value in Enum.GetValues(input.GetType()))
        if (input.HasFlag(value))
            yield return value;
}
```

Credit to @Greg ([Iterate over values in Flags Enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171140/iterate-over-values-in-flags-enum))

Then call it as such:

```
List<string> names = GetFlags(enumValue).Select(e => e.ToString()).ToList();
```