# Getting error when trying to enumerate enum

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums

I have the following model:

```
public class FormModel
{
  public Guid {get; set;}
  public Sections Sections {get; set}
}

[Flags]
    public enum Sections
    {
        Test1= 0,
        Test2= 1,
        Test3= 2,
        Test4= 4,
        Test5= 8,
        Test6= 16
    }
```

I'm using a service that returns the model with data:

```
var form = await _formService.GetById(formAnswer.FormId);
```

Now the Sections-property contains: `Test1 | Test2`

I'm trying to enumerate this property like this:

```
 var list = new List<string>();
 foreach(var item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(form.Sections)))
 {
     //Add the form.Sections into the list.
 }
```

But I get the error:

> 'form' is a variable but is used like a type

How can I enumerate the Sections-property of my model and add the values to a list?

Comment: The type is `typeof(Sections)`. You're passing some Sections value to`typeof`.

Comment: Use form.Sections.GetType()

Comment: @CharlesMager: So how should I do insead?

Comment: @Bryan like I said - `typeof(Sections)`.

Comment: @CharlesMager: 
 
But If I do this, I enumerate the whole enum. Not the Sections-property from my result from the service..

Comment: @Bryan ah, OK. Missed that subtlety. Will link to duplicate...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate over values in Flags Enum?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171140/iterate-over-values-in-flags-enum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a typo. You used the form instance, instead you wanted the type of the enum. Try:

```
foreach (var item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Sections)))
{
    if (((int)form.Sections & (int)item) != 0)
    {
         // add to list
    }
}
```

Comment: But If I do this, I enumerate the whole enum. Not the Sections-property from my result from the service..

Comment: @Bryan Ah, now I see what you wanted, check the update

Comment: Hehe, I tried like your answer before with this:   if ((int)form.Sections & (int)item) > 0)
                {

                }, but I got a error. Now I see that I forgot a parentheses. Thank you!

Comment: You can also use `if(form.Sections.HasFlag(item))`, to hide the casting and boolean logic.