# Should "or" work with .Net4 Hasflags: enum.HasFlag(AccessRights.Read | AccessRights.Write)

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, enums, enum-flags

I am trying out the new HasFlags features, and was wondering if the following *should* work:

> enum.HasFlag(AccessRights.Read | AccessRights.Write)

... because it doesn't seem to...

```
 DBAccessRights rights = (DBAccessRights)permission.PermissionFlags;
  if (rights.HasFlag(DBAccessRights.WikiMode))
  {
     // works
  }


  if (rights.HasFlag(DBAccessRights.WikiMode | DBAccessRights.CreateNew))
  {
     // Doesn't work    
  }

  DBAccessRights flags = DBAccessRights.WikiMode | DBAccessRights.CreateNew;
  if (rights.HasFlag(flags))
  {
     // Doesn't work
  }
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Given [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.hasflag), I'd expect that to return true if the value has *both* of those flags.

If you want it to test whether your value has *either* of those flags, you'll need

```
value.HasFlag(AccessRights.Read) | value.HasFlag(AccessRights.Write)
```

If that's not good readable enough for you, you may want to look at my [Unconstrained Melody](https://github.com/jskeet/unconstrained-melody) project. It so happens that that already has the functionality you want (as extension methods in [`Flags.cs`](https://github.com/jskeet/unconstrained-melody/blob/master/UnconstrainedMelody/Flags.cs#L67-L90)):

```
// Same as value.HasFlag(AccessRights.Read | AccessRights.Write)
value.HasAll(AccessRights.Read | AccessRights.Write)

// Same as value.HasFlag(AccessRights.Read) | value.HasFlag(AccessRights.Write)
value.HasAny(AccessRights.Read | AccessRights.Write)
```

Those would make it clearer, IMO. They'd also avoid boxing, and be typesafe :)

Comment: Does boxing explain the performance note at the bottom of the documentation?

Comment: @makerofthings7: Maybe - it's hard to say for sure. It'd be interesting to measure the difference in performance between the framework and my implementation :)

Comment: @LamonteCristo This method must also do a type check before the unboxing. They want to throw an `ArgumentException` if you pass a reference of a wrong type. I wonder if the type check is done again during unboxing. We can check the bytecode or the C# source.

Comment: For Any, why would you not just do (AccessRights.Read | AccessRights.Write).HasFlag(value) ?

Comment: @JonSkeet I kind of love this. I want to write a few extensions of my own using this code, so I sort of shamelessly ripped your source code off GitHub. I left a text-file in my source code sourcing you and giving you credit though, so I hope you're not mad.

Comment: @Will: How could I possibly be mad? It's open source - that's the point :) Glad it's useful!

Comment: Just incase anyone wants a direct link to the file that contains the `HasAll()` method `https://github.com/jskeet/unconstrained-melody/blob/master/UnconstrainedMelody/Flags.cs`.

Answer (score 20):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx):

> The HasFlag method returns the result of the following Boolean
>   expression.
>
> thisInstance And flag = flag

For a complex flag such as `AccessRights.Read | AccessRights.Write`, this will check that *all* the "contained" flags are present.

You probably want to check that *any* of the flags are present, in which case you can do:

```
myAccessRights & (AccessRights.Read | AccessRights.Write) != 0
```

Comment: Well I'm torn between accepting this vs Jon Skeet's answer.  It's the performance optimal way of achieving my goal.  His answer explains what I did wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The `|` operator is bitwise or. It means that if `Read` is 1 and `Write` is 2, the value `Read | Write` is 3 (see its binary representation). So `HasFlag` returns true only if your `enum` variable have **both** `Read` and `Write` set.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could just reverse the order of the expression:

```
//returns true - a bit easier on the eye
(AccessRights.Read | AccessRights.Write).HasFlag(myAccessRights)
```

This will return true if you have *either* Read | Write access. That would be  functionally equivalent to:

```
//also returns true - as per @Ani's answer
myAccessRights & (AccessRights.Read | AccessRights.Write) != 0
```

**EDIT**

As pointed out in the comments, The first expression will return true if myAccessRights is empty, and false if myAccessRights has more than just Read and Write.

Comment: It returns true if myAccessRights has no flag set what is not right. But anyway. Like this approach

Comment: It is not functionally equivalent unless you are assuming that Read and Write are the only flags defined in AccessRights - which you shouldn't even if it is true. The first expression will return false if myAccessRights has any flags set other than read or write.

Answer (score 1):

In a flagged enum you could simply do:

```
(MyEnum01 & MyEnum02) != 0
```

If there are *any* common bits, a bit will be set and thus the number is no longer 0. If there are *no* common bits, the result is 0. For that the flagged enum for 0 should represent "none".

Here is a static method for generic enums and one for a specific one:

```
public static partial class UtilityMethods
{
    public static bool HasAnyFlags (Enum enumA, Enum enumB)
    {
        return ((int) (object) enumA & (int) (object) enumB) != 0;
    }

    public static bool HasAnyFlags (MyEnum enumA, MyEnum enumB)
    {
        return (enumA & enumB) != 0;
    }
}
```

You could also create your own extension method:

```
public static partial class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static bool HasAnyFlag (this Enum e, Enum compared)
    {
        return ((int) (object) e & (int) (object) compared) != 0;
    }
}
```

For the generic enums I took the conversion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51025027/8116738). Allegedly it's more performant to do it with boxing rather than `Converter.ToInt32()`.