# How to cast my own enum type to generic enum type?

Tags: c#, generics, enums, casting

How can I cast my own enum type to generic enum type ?

```
public enum MyEnum
    {
        First,
        Second
    }

    public class MyEnumParser<TEnum>
        where TEnum : struct, Enum
    {
        public static TEnum Parse(string value)
        {
            switch (default(TEnum))
            {
                case MyEnum _: return MyEnum.First;  // Error in this line of code
                default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Type {nameof(TEnum)} not supported.");
            }
        }
    }
```

The compiler won't let me convert the type, even though I'm explicitly checking the type in the switch:

**Cannot implicitly convert type 'ConsoleApp1.MyEnum' to 'TEnum'**

If I try to explicitly cast the type, I get another error:

```
case MyEnum _: return (TEnum)MyEnum.First;
```

**Cannot convert type 'ConsoleApp1.MyEnum' to 'TEnum'**

Upd. I am currently working on System.Text.JSON serializer. This is simplified example.The method must be generic.
Gradually, I will add all my other enumerations to the serializer. I started with one.

Comment: What is the end goal? If you know which values to check before hand, thus know the type of enum, you wouldn't need it to be generic?
(As for parsing, there are several Enum.Parse methods available. Would they do what you need?)

Comment: It seems that the TEnum is not needed here if you are going to return known types.

Comment: You may alread know this but you can assign a enum member to 0 and it will be default(TEnum).

Comment: I am currently working on System.Text.JSON serializer. This is simplified example.The method must be generic.

Comment: You can use the next approach: `case MyEnum _: return (TEnum) (object) MyEnum.First;`. But is it acceptable for you? Are you fine with additional cast to `object`?

Comment: @Iliar Turdushev Yes, casting to object works. Can you write this as an answer ? I'll take it, because it seems to work, but I'm not sure it's the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to cast your custom enum type `MyEnum` to generic enum type `TEnum` is to use the next approach:

```
case MyEnum _: return (TEnum) (object) MyEnum.First;
```

Here are links to similar problems:

- [Value of type 'T' cannot be converted to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4092393/12833205)
- [How do I cast a generic enum to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16960555/12833205)
- [Cast Int to Generic Enum in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10387095/12833205)