# Why is unsafe read sbyte -> byte inconsistent in Release mode: *(byte*)(&sbyteValue)?

Tags: c#, byte, release, unsafe, sbyte

While writing conversion of [generic enum to int](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72838343/2094687) strange things happened around unsafe read of sbyte type to byte.

The folloging examples were tested with .Net 6.0 on AMD x64 machine.

**Example 1: Inconsistency Debug vs. Release**

The following code generates different output in Debug and in Release mode:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        byte byteValue = ReadAsByteValue(sbyteValue: -1);

        Console.WriteLine(byteValue);

        // OUTPUT DEBUG:   255
        // OUTPUT RELEASE: -1
    }

    static unsafe byte ReadAsByteValue(sbyte sbyteValue)
    {
        return *(byte*)(&sbyteValue);
    }
}
```

Since type `byte` does not have value -1, I suppose that in Release mode the compiler returns `sbyte` instead of `byte`.

**Example 2A: Inconsistency in Release mode**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var value1 = GetIntValueEncapsulated((sbyte)-1, true);
        var value2 = GetIntValue((sbyte)-1);

        Console.WriteLine($"{value1} vs. {value2}");

        foreach (var value in Array.Empty<sbyte>())
        {
            GetIntValueEncapsulated(value, true);
        }

        // OUTPUT RELEASE: -1 vs. 255
    }

    static int GetIntValueEncapsulated<T>(T value, bool trueFalse)
        where T : unmanaged
    {
        if (trueFalse)
        {
            return GetIntValue(value);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException($"Not implemented for size: {Unsafe.SizeOf<T>()}");
        }
    }

    static unsafe int GetIntValue<T>(T value)
        where T : unmanaged
    {
        return *(byte*)(&value);
    }
}
```

**Example 2B: Commenting out empty `foreach` changes results**

```
var value1 = GetIntValueEncapsulated((sbyte)-1, true);
var value2 = GetIntValue((sbyte)-1);

Console.WriteLine($"{value1} vs. {value2}");

//foreach (var value in Array.Empty<sbyte>())
//{
//    GetIntValueEncapsulated(value, true);
//}

// OUTPUT RELEASE: -1 vs. -1
```

**Example 2C: Non-functional change on the Exception line changes results**

Starting with Example 2A and replacing line:

```
throw new NotImplementedException($"Not implemented for size: {Unsafe.SizeOf<T>()}");
```

with line:

```
throw new NotImplementedException($"Not implemented for size: " + Unsafe.SizeOf<T>());
```

gives output:

```
// OUTPUT RELEASE: 255 vs. 255
```

**Questions**

- What is the exact cause of these differences?
- How to force compiler in the Release mode to behave as expected? (i.e. as in the Debug mode)

Comment: Side note: you should probably use `Unsafe.As` rather than your own unsafe code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Example 1: Inconsistency Debug vs. Release**

1. You should know that the overload method chosen by the compiler in this example is `WriteLine(int)`. So if you call `WriteLine((uint)byteValue)` or `WriteLine(byteValue.ToString())`, you'll get the result `255`.
2. The compiler prefers 32-bit signed integer types today and will encode `sbyteValue: -1` to `ffffffff` not `000000ff` because of the efficiency.
3. The side-effect of optimzation in release mode.

```
// Release
ldc.i4.m1
call uint8 C::ReadAsByteValue(int8)
call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)

// Debug
ldc.i4.m1
call uint8 C::ReadAsByteValue(int8)
stloc.0
ldloc.0
call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
```

You can see in debug mode, it uses a local variable to transmit the byte. The docs of `stloc` says.

> Storing into locals that hold an integer value smaller than 4 bytes long truncates the value as it moves from the stack to the local variable.

Since there is no middleman in release mode, no truncation, `WriteLine` method will use the return value `ffffffff` in the register as is. The effect also applies to `short+ushort` with the same reason.

---

**Example 2A: Inconsistency in Release mode**

According to the explaination above the values returned from `GetIntValueEncapsulated` or `GetIntValue` in the registers are always `ffffffff`.

Sorry I'm not a JIT expert, so I can't tell the implemention detail. What I know is this is caused by method inlining. Apply `NoInlining` to the method, the output is -1.

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
static unsafe int GetIntValue<T>(T value)
```

The following code can be used to simulate the effect of forced inlining.

```
sbyte a = -1;
var value2 = *(byte*)(&a);
```

When the method is inline the compiler uses the following instrument to set the value of value2 which force the type to byte.

```
movzx       edi,byte ptr [rsp+4Ch]
```

---

**To enforce the expected result**

1. Use a deterministic method.

```
Console.WriteLine((uint)byteValue); // Console.WriteLine(uint)
Console.WriteLine(byteValue.ToString()); // byte.ToString()
```

2. Convert to `uint*` first

```
static unsafe byte ReadAsByteValue(sbyte sbyteValue)
    => (byte)*(uint*)(&sbyteValue);
static unsafe int GetIntValue<T>(T value) where T : unmanaged
    => (byte)*(uint*)(&value);
```

Comment: How do you explain why commenting-out the `foreach (var value in Array.Empty<sbyte>())` (which ostensibly does nothing) changes the results?

Comment: @shingo I still do not understand how Example 2B and 2C work: what caused the change of behaviour there?

Comment: Sorry I can't explain it well now, I only know that the second call to `GetIntValue` is inline by jit when foreach exists, it uses a simple way to copy the constant value, but I don't know why jit decides to do so.

Comment: @shingo I marked your answer as Accepted, but could you please answer more properly the second question: "How to force the compiler in the Release mode to behave as expected"?. Could using Unsafe.As<sbyte,byte>() do the trick? Using NoInlining does not enforce it always (tried it). My opinion about the expected result: the "Example 1" should always end up with 255, because: (sbyte)-1 is 11111111 in bits. 11111111 in bits is (byte)255. (byte)255 is (int)255. So: could you please recommend 1 or 2 steps to enforce the expected result?

Comment: @frakon Added approaches at the end.  "(sbyte)-1 is 11111111 in bits" this is only true in theory, In fact a single sbyte or byte in memory is 4 bytes long.