# Pass to a method a subset of enum in C#?

Tags: c#, enumeration

I want to define a method which returns true or false if a subset of an enum (first argument) contains an enum element (second element)

In other words, having an enum like:

```
public enum type { INST, INST_NAME, OPEN_BR, CLOSED_BR};
```

I wish to define a method like this one:

```
public bool check (IEnumerable <type> subset , type t)
       {if(subset.Contains t)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
       }
```

And then call it with:

```
check(new List<type>{INST, INST_NAME},type.INST);
```

Which returns true since the list contains INST. So the question is: do you know any more elegant way to implement this method (assuming that it works).

**Thank you for your answers!**

Comment: Why not just check if that value of the enum is nothing?

Comment: Err, null. Nothing is the equivalent in VB.net.

Comment: What is the type of "SubsetOfType"? Either I don't understand what you are trying to do, or you are trying do something really wrong with enums

Comment: You can go by two way: 1. pass the list of enums and check, or 2. define enum as flag (if it suitable).

Comment: You don't need to define a method, it already exists: [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains(v=vs.100).ASPX).  `return subset.Contains(t);`

Comment: Sounds like he wants a `[Flags]` enum. Check the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1339976/

Comment: Updated trying to implement a first version (still have to test it)...can you find a better/more elegant version? :)

Comment: @LovaJ. Yes - just use `Contains` - there's no need to break it into its own method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a separate method to simplify this - you can just use the built-in `Contains` extension method:

```
var subset = new List<type>{INST, INST_NAME};

bool check = subset.Contains(type.INST);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add [Flags] attribute to your enum. Set each option to be represented by an exclusive bit.

For example:

```
[Flags]
enum LogLevel
{
    App = 1 << 0,
    Exception = 1 << 1,
    Warning = 1 << 2,
    Measurement = 1 << 3,
    User = 1 << 4
}
```

Then implement your method like this:

```
bool IsSet(LogLevel levels, LogLevel levelInQuestion)
{
    return (levels & levelInQuestion) > 0;
}
```

Example Use:

```
LogLevel logLevels = LogLevel.App | LogLevel.Warning | LogLevel.Exception;
bool logWarnings = IsSet(logLevels, LogLevel.Warning);
```