# How to work with integer flags

Tags: c#, enums

I am trying to set an integer variable to a combination of an `enum` values, the `enum` is:

```
public enum WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags : uint
{
    DLIMAGES = 0x00000010,
    VIDEOS = 0x00000020,
    BGSOUNDS = 0x00000040,
    NO_SCRIPTS = 0x00000080,
    NO_JAVA = 0x00000100,
    NO_RUNACTIVEXCTLS = 0x00000200,
    NO_DLACTIVEXCTLS = 0x00000400,
    DOWNLOADONLY = 0x00000800,
    NO_FRAMEDOWNLOAD = 0x00001000,
    RESYNCHRONIZE = 0x00002000,
    PRAGMA_NO_CACHE = 0x00004000,
    NO_BEHAVIORS = 0x00008000,
    NO_METACHARSET = 0x00010000,
    URL_ENCODING_DISABLE_UTF8 = 0x00020000,
    URL_ENCODING_ENABLE_UTF8 = 0x00040000,
    NOFRAMES = 0x00080000,
    FORCEOFFLINE = 0x10000000,
    NO_CLIENTPULL = 0x20000000,
    SILENT = 0x40000000,
    OFFLINEIFNOTCONNECTED = 0x80000000,
    OFFLINE = OFFLINEIFNOTCONNECTED,
}
```

The `DownloadControlFlags` is an integer field:

```
    public int DownloadControlFlags
    {
        get
        {
            return _downloadControlFlags;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_downloadControlFlags == value)
                return;

            _downloadControlFlags = value;
            IOleControl ctl = (IOleControl)ActiveXInstance;
            ctl.OnAmbientPropertyChange(DISPID_AMBIENT_DLCONTROL);
        }
    }
```

To set this variable I used summation as :

```
  webBrowser1.DownloadControlFlags = (int)WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags.DLIMAGES
             + (int)WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags.NOFRAMES
             + (int)WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags.NO_FRAMEDOWNLOAD
             + (int)WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags.NO_JAVA
             + (int)WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags.NO_DLACTIVEXCTLS
             + (int)WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags.NO_BEHAVIORS
             + (int)WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags.NO_RUNACTIVEXCTLS
        + (int)WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags.SILENT;
```

I am not sure if it is the correct way, but it seems that it works. But now I want to check if the variable contains an specific value or not. For normal `enum` the solution could be the answer of this question [How to check if any flags of a flag combination are set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339976/how-to-check-if-any-flags-of-a-flag-combination-are-set), but I am not sure if I can use the same way in my case.

How can I check if a specific flag has been set or not?! for example if the `DownloadControlFlags` contains `WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags.NO_JAVA` or not!

Comment: You can convert the int to an enum, and check the flags on it: `WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags foo = (WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags)yourInt;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For normal `enum` the solution could be the answer of this question [How to check if any flags of a flag combination are set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339976/how-to-check-if-any-flags-of-a-flag-combination-are-set), but I am not sure if I can use the same way in my case.

Have you tried it?

```
int flags = (int)WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags.DLIMAGES
         + (int)WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags.NOFRAMES
         + (int)WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags.NO_FRAMEDOWNLOAD
         + (int)WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags.NO_JAVA
         + (int)WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags.NO_DLACTIVEXCTLS
         + (int)WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags.NO_BEHAVIORS
         + (int)WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags.NO_RUNACTIVEXCTLS
         + (int)WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags.SILENT;
```

You can either use [`Enum.HasFlag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx) by casting it back to your enum type:

```
Console.WriteLine(((WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags)flags).HasFlag(WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags.NOFRAMES)); // true
Console.WriteLine(((WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags)flags).HasFlag(WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags.VIDEOS)); // false
```

Or you can cast the enum flag you want to compare against into an int and then make a bit-wise comparison:

```
Console.WriteLine((flags & (int)WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags.NO_JAVA) != 0); // true
Console.WriteLine((flags & (int)WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags.VIDEOS) != 0); // false
```

But you should really consider whether you actually don’t want to store the flags internally as a `WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags` type. There is no reason to convert it into an int early. And you could just as well do the following:

```
WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags flags = WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags.DLIMAGES
         | WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags.NOFRAMES
         | WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags.NO_FRAMEDOWNLOAD
         | WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags.NO_JAVA
         | WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags.NO_DLACTIVEXCTLS
         | WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags.NO_BEHAVIORS
         | WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags.NO_RUNACTIVEXCTLS
         | WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags.SILENT;

Console.WriteLine(flags.HasFlag(WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags.NOFRAMES)); // true
Console.WriteLine(flags.HasFlag(WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags.VIDEOS)); // false

Console.WriteLine((flags & WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags.NO_JAVA) != 0); // true
Console.WriteLine((flags & WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags.VIDEOS) != 0); // false
```

And whenever you really *need* an int value, you can just convert the whole thing into an int:

```
Console.WriteLine((int)flags); // 1074304784
```

Comment: Thank you very much, as I used a code in which they defined the variable as integer, I wasn't sure how to change their code!

Comment: To answer your question, yes I tried it and `&` and `|` operators are not applicable on integers.

Comment: Yes, they are. They are bitwise operators and work fine on integers (as shown in the second example above).