# C# Enum Flags Comparison

Tags: c#, enums

Given the following flags,

```
  [Flags]
    public enum Operations
    {
        add = 1,
        subtract = 2,
        multiply = 4,
        divide = 8,
        eval = 16,
    }
```

How could I implement an IF condition to perform each operation? In my attempt, the first condition is true for **add, eval**, which is correct. However the first condition is also true for **subtract, eval**, which is incorrect.

```
        public double Evaluate(double input)
    {
        if ((operation & (Operations.add & Operations.eval)) == (Operations.add & Operations.eval))
            currentResult += input;
        else if ((operation & (Operations.subtract & Operations.eval)) == (Operations.subtract & Operations.eval))
            currentResult -= input;
        else
            currentResult = input;

        operation = null;

        return currentResult;
    }
```

I cannot see what the problem is.

Comment: Is it just me who thinks [Flags] for the operation shown is not correct? I am struggling to think of a real world sample where I would have Flags on mathematical operations shown...

Comment: I agree Sunny. The flags were supposed to represent states in a calculator. I'm not sure why I did it this way. In retrospect, I wouldn't do it this way now days.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Compare Flags in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40211/how-to-compare-flags-in-c)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Change your inner `&` to `|`:

```
if ((operation & (Operations.add | Operations.eval)) == (Operations.add | Operations.eval))
```

This is equivalent to:

```
if( ((operation & Operations.add)==Operations.add) &&
    ((operation & Operations.eval)==Operations.eval))
```

which might be more readable. You might also want to consider an Extension like this:

```
public static bool HasFlag(this Operations op, Operations checkflag)
{
    return (op & checkflag)==checkflag;
}
```

then you can do this:

```
if(operation.HasFlag(Operations.add) && Operations.HasFlag(Operations.eval))
```

which might be even more readable. Finally you could create this extension for even more fun:

```
public static bool HasAllFlags(this Operations op, params Operations[] checkflags)
{
    foreach(Operations checkflag in checkflags)
    {
        if((op & checkflag)!=checkflag)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then your expression could turn into:

```
if(operation.HasAllFlags(Operations.add, Operations.eval))
```

Comment: Unless you find this unreadable, do you need seperate `HasAllFlags`, because you can use `HasFlag` like so: `if(operation.HasFlag(Operations.add | Operations.eval))`.

Answer (score 12):

Wow, I can't believe all of the wrong answers..

It's important to understand bitwise math if you're working with flags.  In your case, you have the following (for the first condition):

```
1 in binary is  00001
16 in binary is 10000

  00001
& 10000
--------
  00000
```

So, say we have Subtract (2) as the `operation`

```
2 in binary is     00010
previous result is 00000

  00010
& 00000
--------
  00000
```

Since the previous result is `00000` anything AND'd with it will be zero.  So your condition will always evaluate to `true` since `0 == 0`.

If we *just* switch this to OR, then we have the following:

```
1 in binary is  00001
16 in binary is 10000

  00001
| 10000
--------
  10001 (17)
```

Now, say we have `Add (1)` as the `operation`

```
1 in binary is     00001
previous result is 10001 (17)

  00001
& 10001
--------
  00001
```

So, `1 & 17 => 1` and thus your final condition is `(1 & ( 1 | 16 ) ) == ( 1 | 16 )` => `1 & 17 == 17` => `1 == 17` => `false` (**still false!**)

So what you actually want is:

```
((operation | Operations.add | Operations.eval) & (Operations.add | Operations.eval)) == (Operations.add | Operations.eval)
```

This becomes `((1 | 1 | 16 ) & ( 1 | 16 )) == ( 1 | 16 )` => `( 17 & 17 ) == 17` => `17 == 17` == `true`

This is obviously not readable, so you should opt for extracting this into a method (as suggested).  But it's still important to *understand why* your condition is incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

Duplicate:

See [How to Compare Flags in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40211/how-to-compare-flags-in-c)

C# 4 introduces the [Enum.HasFlags()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx) method.

However, see [What is it that makes Enum.HasFlag so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368652/what-is-it-that-makes-enum-hasflag-so-slow) if perfomance is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your operation is failing is because you have the wrong expression.  `(Operations.add & Operations.eval)` is *always* zero.  Left and right side of your first comparison are both always zero.  Try this instead - I suspect it's what you were after:

```
public double Evaluate(double input)
{
    if ((operation & (Operations.add | Operations.eval)) == (Operations.add | Operations.eval))
        currentResult += input;
    else if ((operation & (Operations.subtract | Operations.eval)) == (Operations.subtract | Operations.eval))
        currentResult -= input;
    else
        currentResult = input;

    operation = null;

    return currentResult;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   public double Evaluate(double input)
{
    if ((operation & (Operations.add | Operations.eval)) == (Operations.add | Operations.eval))
        currentResult += input;
    else if ((operation & (Operations.subtract | Operations.eval)) == (Operations.subtract | Operations.eval))
        currentResult -= input;
    else
        currentResult = input;

    operation = null;

    return currentResult;
}
```