# Using Automapper with Flags Enum

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to figure out how to use AutoMapper with the following scenario :-

I have the following Entity Model :-

```
public class Lender : LegacyEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ClaimType ClaimTypes { get; set; }

        //Other properties kepy out for brevity.
    }
```

And Here is The Following Service Model :-

```
public class LenderServiceModel 
    {
        [Editable(false)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Editable(false)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Editable(false)]
        public List<string> ClaimTypes { get; set; }
    }
```

In the case of the Entity model, the ClaimType property is a Flags Enum :-

```
 [Flags]
    public enum ClaimType : int
    {
        A = 1,
        B = 2,
        C = 4,

    }
```

I want to be able to map from the Entity Model, to the Service Model. I need to map the ClaimType to List on the Service Model, but i have had no luck.

I'm new to AutoMapper, any help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a property mapping for ClaimTypes, which converts each flags value to a string. There are a few ways to do this. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112076/list-all-bit-names-from-a-flag-enum) for some ideas.

Here's how you can set it up in AutoMapper (using a quick and dirty method of just `ToString()`ing the enum then splitting the string):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Lender, LenderServiceModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ClaimTypes, opts => opts.MapFrom(src =>
        src.ClaimTypes.ToString().Split(new string[]{", "}, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList()));
```

You can see a working [.NETFiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/in7lwk)

Comment: Thanks for this. appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to get hold of a string list representation of your enum flags, this can be done with this statement

```
var t = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ClaimType)).Cast<ClaimType>().Where(r => (claimType & r) == r).Select(r => r.ToString()).ToList();
```

For specific mappings with AutoMapper you need to specify it while setting it up.
So for this that will be following code: so we map ClaimTypes field from source to destination using the list conversion...

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<LegacyEntity, LenderServiceModel >()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ClaimTypes,
               opts => opts.MapFrom(Enum.GetValues(typeof(ClaimType)).Cast<ClaimType>().Where(r => (src.ClaimTypes & r) == r).Select(r => r.ToString()).ToList());
```