# Reading a bitfield (used for Selected Days) and determining values from it in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, bit, bit-fields

I have a column of type int called SelectedDays in my database. I decided to go with the bit approach:

```
sun=1, mon=2, tue=4, wed=8, thu=16, fri=32, sat=64
```

If the user selects Sun, Mon, Wed then the value in the field would be 11

In my C# model I am trying to make a readonly property:

```
public List<string> Days
```

that will return a list of the selected days in string format.

I can't figure out how to go from 11 to "Sunday", "Monday", "Wednesday"

Comment: This should do the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112076/list-all-bit-names-from-a-flag-enum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int valueFromDb = 11;
var result = Enum.GetNames(typeof(WeekDays))
                 .Where(x => (valueFromDb & (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(WeekDays), x)) > 0)
                 .ToList();
```

You can do it like this. [**Full example**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2d8AJ3)