# Working out Enum masks c#

Tags: c#, enums

I was wondering how the following enum masking works

If I have an Enum structure

```
public enum DelMask
{
        pass = 1,       
        fail = 2,       
        abandoned = 4,        
        distinction = 8,             
        merit = 16,        
        defer = 32,        
}
```

I have seen the following code

```
int pass = 48;
if ((pass & (int)DelMask.defer) > 0)
   //Do something
else if ((pass & (int)DelMask.merit ) > 0)
   //Do something else
```

I am wondering can anyone help me figure out how which block will get executed?

Comment: `int pass == 48;` shouldn't compile is it `int pass = 48` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Compare Flags in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40211/how-to-compare-flags-in-c)

Comment: Just to be sure... your enum has the [Flags] attribute, right?

Comment: @Marc-AndréJutras no it is not included. This is code that I am trying to figure out

Comment: Only difference with [Flags] is that you would not have to write the int values in the definition of the enum members. I think there might be some optimizations in the VS code analysis tools too when you use Flags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic bit logic at work here. The integer 48 ends like this in binary:

```
0011 0000
```

Defer, 32, is:

```
0010 0000
```

Merit, 16, is:

```
0001 0000
```

Now when you perform a logical AND (&), the resulting bits are set where they are both in the input:

```
pass & (int)DelMask.defer

0011 0000 
0010 0000
========= & 
0010 0000
```

The result will be 16, so `((pass & (int)DelMask.defer) > 0)` will evaluate to true. Both `if`'s will evaluate to true in your example because both flags are present in the input. The second one won't be evaluated though, because it's an `else if`.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct so the first will get executed.

16 is 10000

32 is 100000

48 is 16+32 so it is 110000

10000 & 110000 is 10000

100000 & 110000 is 100000

Both are bigger than zero.

Answer (score 1):

48 = 16 (merit) + 32 (defer).

Thus `pass & (int)DelMask.defer` evaluates to 32, so the first block runs.

If that wasn't the case, `pass & (int)DelMask.merit` evaluates to 16, so the second block would run if it got that far.

This only works because the values in the enum are all different powers of 2 and thus correspond to independent bits in the underlying `int`. This is what is known as a bit flags enum.

Answer (score 1):

First, it should be `int pass = 48;`
Basically this code checks whether a bit is set in a binary representation of the number. Each & operation should produce a result with all zeroes and one on the place where it is in the mask. for instance:

```
48:         110000
defer = 32: 100000
            ______
          & 100000
```

So you can use this code:

```
int pass = 48;
if ((pass & (int)DelMask.defer) == (int)DelMask.defer)
   //Do something
else if ((pass & (int)DelMask.merit ) == (int)DelMask.merit)
   //Do something else
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you need to think of those numbers as binary. I'll use the d suffix to show decimal notation and b suffix for binary notation.

enum values:

- 01d = 000001b
- 02d = 000010b
- 04d = 000100b
- 08d = 001000b
- 16d = 010000b
- 32d = 100000b

pass value:

48d = 110000b

Now the `&` is the bit-wise AND operator. Which means that if c = a&b, the nth bit in c will be 1 if and only if the nth bit is 1 in both a and b.

So:

- 16d & 48d = 010000b = 16d > 0
- 32d & 48d = 100000b = 32d > 0

As you see, your number 48d "matches" with both 16d and 32d. That is why this kind of enums is generally described as a "flag" enum: you can have with one integer the value of several "flags".

As for your code, the first `if` operator will be verified, which means that you will enter it and "Do something". You will not "Do something else".

Generally in C#, we use the [[Flags] attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) for flag enums, which allows not actually writing the decimal values for the enum members. As usual, the example in the MSDN is useless so I'll refer to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/enum-flags-attribute) for more details about how to use it (note that to know if a value x has a flag f set, you can either do `x & f == f` or `x | f == x`, but the usage seems to be to generally use the latter one).