# How to prepare audio files (wav or mp3) for Google speech recognition api in c#?

Tags: c#, google-speech-api

```
       String jsonRequest = "{\"config\": {\"languageCode\":\"en-US\"},\"audio\": {\"content\": \"" + base64Content+ "\"}}";
        String str = "";
        var speech = SpeechClient.Create();
        var response = 
        speech.Recognize(RecognizeRequest.Parser.ParseJson(jsonRequest));
        foreach (var result in response.Results)
        {
            foreach (var alternative in result.Alternatives)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(alternative.Transcript);
                str += alternative.Transcript;
            }
        }
```

This code is working fine with mono .wav files but it throws exception for stereo files. The exception says

> Status(StatusCode=InvalidArgument, Detail="Must use single channel (mono) audio, but WAV header indicates 2 channels.")

So, my question is how can I add support for stereo files? How to convert multi channel audio to a single channel in c#? I have already tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25178167/reading-a-single-channel-from-a-multi-channel-wav-file?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) so plz don't refer to it. It is not working.

Comment: _"I have already tried this answer so plz don't refer to it. It is not working"_ - but it contains the answer. If you can't get it to work, create a [mcve] and ask for help getting it to work. Or choose an existing audio library and call it to obtain the single channel or downmixed audio.

Comment: Can you give more information on what you try to achieve? Where do the audiofiles come from? The best way is to fit the audiofile to fit the API and not converting it. Do you have the possibility of using mono files?

Comment: Audio can come from any where. It could be a song, a conversation or a lecture. I can freely browse a file and the code will convert it to text for me. If any selected file is mono then the above code works otherwise Iit doesn't work. I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look into [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html) which can convert nearly any format into another including sample rate conversion, and in your case interesting, channel conversion. In the documentation you find many examples on how to use it.

In your case I would advise against just extracting one channel from the audio because that could mean that the desired audio is only on another channel which is not selected.

If you want to have full control over the audio you could dive into [bass.dll](http://www.un4seen.com/bass.html#addons) in liaison with bass.net.dll, which allows you to mix channels together or select a specific channel.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sox did it.