# How does if((attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == FileAttributes.Hidden) { } work?

Tags: c#, .net, bitmask

On [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getattributes(v=vs.110).aspx) page, I see the following code:

```
if ((attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == FileAttributes.Hidden)
```

But I don't understand *why* it is the way it is.

Why `attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden)`? What does the singular check on `attributes` actually do? Does it check if it's not null? I have a feeling I know, but it seems weird. Random and weird.

Comment: Use Enum.HasFlag instead (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Read the [FileAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes(v=vs.110).aspx) page as well.  It states taht the type has a FlagsAttribute attribute, which means the value is treated as a collection of logical flags, rather than a set of values.  This means you use the logical AND (`&`) and OR (`|`) operatotros to check it's flag fields.

Comment: See this answer to a similar question. Very well written IMO. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1769814/1260204

Comment: Do be aware that if you use [`HasFlag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that [it is slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368652/what-is-it-that-makes-enum-hasflag-so-slow).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's simple boolean logic. The `==` operator only returns `true` if both sides have the exact same value. So you have to *mask* the `attributes` value with the flag you want to compare against. Consider those two examples (values are made up):

true:

```
  0010001 // attributes
& 0000001 // FileAttributes.Hidden
  -------
= 0000001 // FileAttributes.Hidden
```

false:

```
  0011000 // attributes
& 0000001 // FileAttributes.Hidden
  -------
= 0000000 // FileAttributes.None
```

Answer (score 4):

`attributes` is of `FileAttributes` type. This type is an `enum`, a value type. It is not `FileAttributes?` (`Nullable<FileAttributes>`), so it simply **cannot be null**.

Every `enum` consists of a list of named values, but each of them is mappable/convertible to some integer (int) values. In many places C# allows you to "exploit" that conversion and (somewhat) treat enum values as if they were ints, but still they are not.

For example, the & operator performs what you'd expect - it performs binary AND. This way, if the enum value, converted to integer, has relevant bit(s) set, you will get some nonzero result.

In a "good old way" of checking if some flags/bits are present in some status value. You may often see expression like `foo & FLAG != 0` which checks if the flag is set, or `foo & (FLAG|BLAG) != 0` that checks if any of those two is set. This is a little flawed/dangerous because if someone changes FLAG to have more than one bit, then such expressions would check if ANY bit is set, not if the whole such "multi-bit flag" is set. That's why you may also often see `foo & FLAG == FLAG` that applies the bitmask and checks if the result IS the bitmask, so it checks if all bits of mask are set.

Here, in your case it's just that. Since in that expression you are ANDing and COMPARING with the same mask, you are effectively checking if ALL bits of the mask are set. But that's superfluous as the FileAttributes is clearly marked  as [Flags], the `Hidden` value has just one bit, so != 0 would be enough.

However, in such cases (checking flags, not fancy bitwise masks) you may try to use Enum.HasFlag method, most people will advise you to use it, since it's designed to such cases ;)

This however is not always the best pick. Please see:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/441086/NETs-Enum-HasFlag-and-performance-costs
- http://www.dotnetbitsandpieces.com/?p=11

..but I would be suprised if that performance cost would be an issue to you. Optimizing to this point is very rarely needed.

Answer (score 3):

& is a bitwise and operator.

This operator just performs a bitwise AND to 2 sets of bits.

```
0 & 0 === 0
1 & 0 === 0
0 & 1 === 0
1 & 1 === 1
```

Next to the and operator, there also exists an OR (|) and XOR (exclusive OR) (^) operator.

Comment: ^ is a XOR operator, ~ is a NOT. XOR means "1 if either one but not both bits are 1", NOT means "1 if both bits are 0".