# Bitwise AND To Check Equality

Tags: c#, boolean-logic

If you have a `[Flags]` enum instance called `typeToAdjust`, and you want to see if it's equal to clientType, is there any point doing this?

```
 (clientType & (int)typeToAdjust) == (int)typeToAdjust
```

Doesn't this do the same?:

```
clientType == (int)typeToAdjust
```

Comment: Did you mistype the second statement? Did you meant `&` instead of `==` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Compare Flags in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40211/how-to-compare-flags-in-c)

Comment: not really an answer to that specific question ; but from FW4.5 you can use the [HasFlag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to simplify things ; it will do exactly that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have more than one flag set in clientType, then you must do the first one, although you could do this also:

```
(clientType & (int)typeToAdjust) != 0
```

You seem to have missed the whole idea of `[Flags]` which allows one or more bits to be set.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but the point of having a flags enum is so you can combine them so

```
   typeToAdjust = type1 
   clientType = type1 | type2
   (clientType & (int)typeToAdjust) == (int)typeToAdjust // true
   clientType == (int)typeToAdjust // false
```

Answer (score 0):

The two statements are different, but the second is the one that actually tests equality. If `clientType` has a superset of the bits set in `typeToAdjust`, then the first expression will evaluate to true since `(clientType & (int)typeToAdjust)` just evaluates to `typeToAdjust`. By superset, I mean that all of the bits set in `typetoAdjust` are set in `clientType`, but maybe some additional bits as well.

Answer (score 0):

(clientType & (int)typeToAdjust) == (int)typeToAdjust

and 
clientType == (int)typeToAdjust

Are not the same

Take clientType = 3 and typeToAdjust = 1

clientType & (int)typeToAdjust = 1 = typeToAdjust
but clientType != (int)typeToAdjust