# How to check if user have ReadAccess for an account in Dynamics CRM usind C#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, access-rights

I am following [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.retrieveprincipalaccessrequest.aspx) walkthrough for getting the access of a user to an account in dynamics crm using C#. When I tried to check that if user have AppendAccess it is not working properly and while debugging I found these rights in the following form.
[image]

I want to check if a user have AppendAccess then do the next. what I tried is in the following:

```
if(principalAccessRes.AccessRights.Equal("AppendAccess "))
{
Console.WriteLine("User have Append Access");
}
```

Comment: AccessRights is a [Flags] enum. So, this is answered by [How to Compare Flags in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40211/how-to-compare-flags-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `AccessRights` is a `[Flag]` you need to check if the access rights response includes (HAVE) instead of equal.

```
if(principalAccessRes.AccessRights.HasFlag(AccessRights.AppendAccess))
{
   Console.WriteLine("User have Append Access");
}
```