# How do I use .Net Generics to inherit a template parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

**I want to be able to do this.**

```
MyInterface interface = new ServiceProxyHelper<ProxyType>();
```

**Here's the object structure**

```
MyTypeThatImplementsMyInterface : MyInterface
```

**Will this work?**

```
public class ProxyType : MyInterface {}

public class ServiceProxyHelper<ProxyType> : IDisposable, MyInterface {}
```

Comment: Related question:<br>
[Create Generic method constraining T to an Enum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum#79142)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
public class ServiceProxyHelper<T> where T : MyInterface { ... }
```