# Finding the Highest Value in an Enumeration

Tags: c#, arrays, enums

I'm writing a method which determines the highest value in a .NET enumeration so I can create a BitArray with one bit for each enum value:

```
pressedKeys = new BitArray(highestValueInEnum<Keys>());
```

I need this on two different enumerations, so I turned it into a generic method:

```
/// <summary>Returns the highest value encountered in an enumeration</summary>
/// <typeparam name="EnumType">
///   Enumeration of which the highest value will be returned
/// </typeparam>
/// <returns>The highest value in the enumeration</returns>
private static int highestValueInEnum<EnumType>() {
  int[] values = (int[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumType));
  int highestValue = values[0];
  for(int index = 0; index < values.Length; ++index) {
    if(values[index] > highestValue) {
      highestValue = values[index];
    }
  }

  return highestValue;
}
```

As you can see, I'm casting the return value of Enum.GetValues() to int[], not to EnumType[]. This is because I can't cast EnumType (which is a generic type parameter) to int later.

The code works. But is it valid?
Can I always cast the return from Enum.GetValues() to int[]?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the max value of an enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203377/getting-the-max-value-of-an-enum)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, you can't safely cast to `int[]`. Enum types don't always use `int` as an underlying value. If you restrict yourself to enum types which *do* have an underlying type of `int`, it should be fine though.

This feels like something you (or I) could extend [Unconstrained Melody](http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody) to support if you wanted - in a way which genuinely constrained the type to be an enum type at compile time, and worked for *any* enum type, even those with underlying bases such as `long` and `ulong`.

Without Unconstrained Melody, you can still do this in a general way using the fact that all the enum types effectively implement `IComparable` appropriately. If you're using .NET 3.5 it's a one-liner:

```
private static TEnum GetHighestValue<TEnum>() {
  return Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).Cast<TEnum>().Max();
}
```

Comment: Jon, why does the Microsoft reference say "The default underlying type of the enumeration elements is int" if I can't assign any other type to an enum value, neither other integer types other than int32. I just tried to assign 3L to an enum value and got a compilation error.

Comment: Thanks for reporting the twisted assignment in the loop. I already discovered it myself and ninja'd a corrected version into place while you must have been writing your post ;-)

Comment: @André Pena: The *default* underlying type is an enum, but you can declare an enum as "enum Foo : long" instead (etc). See the C# language specification for more details.

Comment: @Jo Skeet: Now I understand it perfectly. I am able to assign a 3L value to an enum item as long I declare the enum as being a long enum. :) thank you.

Answer (score 3):

As per Jon Skeet's advice (and thank you too, slugster), this is the updated code, now using IComparable because I'm still targeting .NET 2.0.

```
/// <summary>Returns the highest value encountered in an enumeration</summary>
/// <typeparam name="EnumType">
///   Enumeration of which the highest value will be returned
/// </typeparam>
/// <returns>The highest value in the enumeration</returns>
private static EnumType highestValueInEnum<EnumType>() where EnumType : IComparable {
  EnumType[] values = (EnumType[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumType));
  EnumType highestValue = values[0];
  for(int index = 0; index < values.Length; ++index) {
    if(values[index].CompareTo(highestValue) > 0) {
      highestValue = values[index];
    }
  }

  return highestValue;
}
```

For anyone grabbing the code, you might want to add an additional check so it doesn't blow up on empty enums.

Comment: Surely `Array.Sort<EnumType>(values);` would be better than your loop?

Comment: It would be shorter, but why sort an array that I'm going to throw away after I'm done? Maybe I'm micro-optimizing here, but Array.Sort() just doesn't seem intuitive to me.

Answer (score 1):

Using some modern C# features we can do this more elegantly:

```cs
static int MaxEnumValue<T>()
    where T : struct, Enum
{
    return (int)(ValueType)Enum.GetValues<T>().Max();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy! Using LINQ your loop can be replaced with two lines of code, or just one if you want to munge it all together.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyEnum z = MyEnum.Second;
        z++;
        z++;

        //see if a specific value is defined in the enum:
        bool isInTheEnum = !Enum.IsDefined(typeof(MyEnum), z);

        //get the max value from the enum:
        List<int> allValues = new List<int>(Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<int>());
        int maxValue = allValues.Max();
    }


}

public enum MyEnum 
{
    Zero = 0,
    First = 1,
    Second = 2,
    Third = 3
}
```

Comment: Why bother creating a `List<int>` though? There's no need to buffer all the values...

Comment: You are totally right, i could have just written it as var max = (from int x in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).AsQueryable() select x).Max(); but that is not very friendly looking piece of code, i wanted to break it down a little and make the code easy to read and informative. And i don't think that "buffering the values" is any less optimal than looping over them to find the highest.